# Clear the terminal in Python

Tags: python, terminal

Does any standard "comes with batteries" method exist to clear the terminal screen from a Python script, or do I have to go [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) (the libraries, not the words)?

Comment: I'd check for Windows and use 'cls' and just unconditionally do a `clear` for everything because that would be likely to cover the most cases. See related question [How to clear python interpreter console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-python-interpreter-console).

Comment: related: [Python - Clearing the terminal screen more elegantly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34388390/4279)

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810537/how-to-clear-the-screen-in-python

Comment: Related (for example, ending here up from a search engine and "Python clear screen REPL"): *[How can I clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/)*. It [boils down to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810537/how-to-clear-the-screen-in-python#comment27752829_4810537) `Ctrl` + `L` on [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) ([Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29), at least).

Comment: It is also in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-the-terminal-in-python/26639250#26639250) here, but it may not actually answer the question. [Noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-the-terminal-in-python/26639250#comment53625039_26639250): *"Not the best answer for those that want to programmatically clear the screen."*

Comment: Perhaps the (original) intent could be made clear in the question? Is it about doing it ***[programmatically](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/programmatically#Adverb)***, from within Python code?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Use [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code):

```
print(chr(27) + "[2J")
```

Comment: this is according to ANSI. makes sense...

Comment: Note that this is not portable across all terminal types... not that you'll run into too many odd types these days...

Comment: This technique brings the cursor down. Try Ctrl+L, the effect is different. I think the script should reset the cursor location to the top of the line.

Comment: This comment will clear the screen but not reset the cursor position. I wanted the cursor position reset as well. The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python#2084560) provided by DaveKirby and edited by @tzot was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Or now, in Python3, print(chr(27) + "[2J")

Comment: print('\x1b[2J')  - works in py3 also

Comment: This works for the Python shell in Enthought Canopy Editor.

Comment: print(chr(27) + "c") or print("\x1bc")

Comment: Hmm it looks like the bash `clear` command is actually doing `print(chr(27) + "[H" + chr(27) + "[J")`. This works for me when I need to do multiple clear screens (after the first, yours won't scroll my terminal for some reason).

Comment: Sorry guys but I couldn't resist: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/real_programmers.png

Comment: @Peter just add `end=''`.

Comment: `print("\033c\033[3J")`

Comment: `print("\033c\033[3J\033[2J\033[0m\033[H")` -  Performs a terminal reset, buffer clearance, clear the window, set back to default colours etc... and places prompt at the top.  -  [source](https://www.unix.com/os-x-apple-/279401-means-clearing-scroll-buffer-osx-terminal.html)

Answer (score 430):

A simple and cross-platform solution would be to use either the `cls` command on Windows, or `clear` on Unix systems. Used with [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system), this makes a nice one-liner:

```
import os
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

Comment: @allyourcode The code in my answer is *explicitly safe* from injections because there is no user input involved there. All the strings that could be passed to `os.system` are fixed.

Comment: The code is explicitly wrong, because you run a whole process  when all you need is to print out some newlines (which is what both `clear` and `cls` do): `print("\n" * 100) `

Comment: @jsbueno I can’t tell about Unix right now, but `cls` on Windows does *not* just print empty lines. It explicitly clears the console buffer, so it is *not* equivalent to printing any amount of whitespace. Also, the code works surprisingly well for something that is “explicitly wrong”. You may dislike it, but that does not make it wrong (not to mention that `cls` on Windows is not a process but a functionality of the console host, e.g. cmd.exe or PowerShell).

Comment: So, that implies that `cls` and `clear` are inherently different - as `clear` is an external process and does not clear the buffer - which makes the solution inconsistent besides inefficient `cls` may be a shell builtin in Windows - but the `system` call will run a new shell nonetheless. 
"The system function passes command to the command interpreter, which executes the string as an operating-system command. system uses the COMSPEC and PATH environment variables to locate the command-interpreter file CMD.exe. " #https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx

Comment: It doesn't entirely clear the screen. It prints a line with `0` (zero). Python 3 interactive on Ubuntu (Python 3.8.10, 2023-11-22).

Answer (score 116):

Simply do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in Windows, or  <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in Mac.

It surely is the simplest way of clearing the screen.

Comment: It is working in centos 7. thanks @sarath joseph

Comment: This is the best answer so far. Also do you know how can i scroll up my python console , because when the screen gets filled I have to write on the last line and it doesn't scroll up.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu and I was using `os.system('clear')` but I think your answer is the simplest way. Upvoted! :)

Comment: @ParagGangil Not the best answer for those that want to _programmatically_ clear the screen.

Comment: How is this answer not at the top, it is by far the best

Comment: That works at the command line, have you actually tried doing it in Python?

Comment: It doesn't work. Just typing ^L in command (Python console in Windows 10)

Comment: I m using Ubuntu and tap "ctrl+L" worked to clean terminal screen, but how can i accomplish this programatically, as the question author asked?

Comment: ctrl+L usually works for all consoles(chrome developer tools console)

Comment: If this is what the OP was asking the question would be off-topic here and would belong on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Answer (score 73):

As for me, the most elegant variant:

```
import os
os.system('cls||clear')
```

Comment: import os and os.system('clear') work on OS X.

Comment: This is actually a really interesting solution - I didn't realize that that was particularly possible...

Comment: @SirJames, really easy. Windows accept "cls" and ignore other and Unix run function which know, ignore "cls"

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the functionality that cmd prompt and bash can do... But it just didn't click that I could do that in Python just as easily.

Comment: Pretty neat... similar to pip3 install clear-screen

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36941376/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 46):

For Windows, Mac and Linux, you can use the following code:

```
import subprocess, platform

if platform.system()=="Windows":
    if platform.release() in {"10", "11"}:
        subprocess.run("", shell=True) #Needed to fix a bug regarding Windows 10; not sure about Windows 11
        print("\033c", end="")
    else:
        subprocess.run(["cls"])
else: #Linux and Mac
    print("\033c", end="")
```

jamesnotjim tested `print("\033c", end="")` for Mac, and I tested it on Linux and Windows (it doesn't work for Windows, hence the other code that calls `cls`). I don't remember who it was I first saw use `print("\033c")` and/or the printf version: `subprocess.run("printf '\033c'", shell=True)`.

rolika pointed out that `end=""` will prevent it from printing a new line afterward.

Note that newer versions of Ubuntu will clear the screen just fine (not just scroll down so it seems cleared) with `clear`, unlike the older versions.

Note that resetting the terminal with ESC c ("\033c") will make the cursor underlined and blinking. If you don't want that, you can use these codes to change it to another style (tested on GNOME Terminal 3.44.0 using VTE 0.68.0 +BIDI +GNUTLS +ICU +SYSTEMD):

- underscore blinking:  "\033[0 q"
- block blinking: "\033[1 q"
- block: "\033[2 q"
- underscore blinking: "\033[3 q"
- underscore: "\033[4 q"
- thin bar blinking: "\033[5 q"
- thin bar: "\033[6 q" (numbers above 6 seem to do this, too)

Also note that you can do any of these things to clear the screen on Linux:

- print("\033c", end=""):
- print("\u001bc", end="")
- print("\U0000001bc", end="")
- print("\x1bc", end="")
- subprocess.run(["clear"]) #This doesn't reset the whole terminal
- subprocess.run('echo -ne "\033c"', shell=True)
- subprocess.run('echo -ne "\ec"', shell=True)
- subprocess.run('echo -ne "\u001bc"', shell=True)
- subprocess.run('echo -ne "\U0000001bc"', shell=True)
- subprocess.run('echo -ne "\x1bc"', shell=True)
- subprocess.run("printf '\033c'", shell=True)
- subprocess.run("printf '\ec'", shell=True)
- subprocess.run("printf '\u001bc'", shell=True)
- subprocess.run("printf '\U0000001bc'", shell=True)
- subprocess.run("printf '\x1bc'", shell=True)

I believe the following code is supposed to clear the content that you have to scroll up to see (but it's difficult to use in conjunction with another command without issues):

- print("\033[3J")

This can do the same thing that `clear` used to do (so you can scroll up to see what was deleted, except it doesn't raise the cursor to the top):

- print("\033[2J")

Comment: This works for me too (using print("\033c"))and I think this is the best solution. No need to import os when comparing against os.system('clear'). It also clears without scrollback.

Comment: Just sending the terminal command to clear screen as described here is in fact a great way of doing it. If you want (much) more elaborate terminal stuff, you can use a library such as [blessings](https://github.com/erikrose/blessings)

Comment: Somebody knows what's mean \033c ?

Comment: @AbyW \033 is the octal number for ESC the escape sequence in ASCII, equivalent to \x1b in hexadecimal. <ESC>c is an escape sequence to reset all terminal settings to default.

Comment: `print("\033c", end="")` if one doesn't want a newline printed

Comment: `print("\033c", end="")` worked nicely with OS X (El Capitan, 10.11.6) running Python 3.7.2. The `subprocess.call()` version worked as well, but the `print()` version is simpler and easier to remember. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is good, it also works in PowerShell, not just cmd.

Comment: Trying this in python 3.7.2 and it does clear the screen. However, when I have more than one page worth of content in the terminal, it only clears all the content available to the current screen. However if you scroll back up, the old content is still there from previous screens. Is there a way to fix this

Comment: @AbyW It should be **FF (Form Feed)** of [C0 control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#C0_control_codes).

Comment: In Windows 10, the subprocess.run("", shell=True) part is required if you use Windows Console Host (the basic Windows terminal) but not required if you use Windows Terminal (the new hotness).

Answer (score 42):

If you are on a Linux/Unix system then printing the [ANSI escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to clear the screen should do the job.  You will also want to move cursor to the top of the screen.  This will work on any terminal that supports ANSI.

```
import sys
sys.stderr.write("\x1b[2J\x1b[H")
```

This will not work on Windows unless ANSI support has been enabled.  There may be an equivalent control sequence for Windows, but I do not know.

Comment: Since your answer implied that you're using Python 2.x, and since 2.x `print` (without `softspace` tuning and/or `sys.stdout.flush()`) can't *ever* leave the cursor at the top-left corner of the screen, I edited your answer to something that can be used in both Python 2.x and 3.x

Comment: For anyone wondering, the string is a series of [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). \x1b[ is a control sequence introducer (hex 0x1B). Code 2J clears the entire screen. Code H sets the cursor position, and without arguments defaults to the top left corner.

Comment: Can you explain why are you writing to stderr instead of stdout, please?

Comment: I can confirm this works with the Linux programs screen and minicom.

Comment: @Aaron My guess would be to prevent the output being buffered. Usually (it might even be in a standard) stderr output is determined to appear imediately.

Comment: I can confirm that stderr is buffered on *my* machine running Arch Linux, zsh, and Python3 inside of tmux (over ssh) - requiring me to run `sys.stderr.flush()`. `print()` actually works just as well.

Comment: `import colorama; colorama.init()` makes `"\x1b[2J\x1b[H"` sequence work on Windows too.

Comment: Calling `os.system('')` makes this work on windows, no external dependencies needed

Answer (score 31):

Just use:

```
print("\033c")
```

This will clear the terminal window.

Comment: also, `print("\033c", end="")` does not inject a newline when clearing console.

Comment: How does this differ from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23075152/1667423) answer?

Comment: @user76284 it is simpler (also this answer is like two years old :o)

Answer (score 11):

I came across this some time ago:

```
def clearscreen(numlines=100):
  """Clear the console.
numlines is an optional argument used only as a fall-back.
"""
# Thanks to Steven D'Aprano, http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums

  if os.name == "posix":
    # Unix, Linux, macOS, BSD, etc.
    os.system('clear')
  elif os.name in ("nt", "dos", "ce"):
    # DOS/Windows
    os.system('CLS')
  else:
    # Fallback for other operating systems.
    print('\n' * numlines)
```

Then just use clearscreen().

Comment: I like how portable this solution is.

Answer (score 11):

This will be work in Both version Python2 OR Python3

```
print (u"{}[2J{}[;H".format(chr(27), chr(27)))
```

Comment: `print (u"{}[2J{}[;H".format(chr(27), chr(27)), end="")` for removing the newline.

Answer (score 10):

You could try to rely on clear but it might not be available on all Linux distributions. On Windows, use [cls](https://ss64.com/nt/cls.html) as you mentioned.

```
import subprocess
import platform

def clear():
    subprocess.Popen("cls" if platform.system() == "Windows" else "clear", shell=True)

clear()
```

Note: It could be considered bad form to take control of the terminal screen.  Are you considering using an option? It would probably be better to let the user decide if he want to clear the screen.

Comment: Why `os.system`? What is the advantage here?

Comment: @TryPyPy My mistake. subprocess is intented to replace os.system, I should be using it instead. OP was right.

Comment: I'd use `subprocess.call()` for something as simple as this call though.

Answer (score 9):

No one has provided a true answer to OP's question it seems. Everyone either responds with '***No don’t use*** os.system(); it's evil!!!' without explanation or provides a solution that relies on printing new lines.

For those that need to clear the terminal screen and scroll back, for whatever reason, you can use the following code:

```
import os

def clear():
    '''
    Clears the terminal screen and scroll back to present
    the user with a nice clean, new screen. Useful for managing
    menu screens in terminal applications.
    '''
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'echo -e \\\\033c')

print('A bunch of garbage so we can garble up the screen...')
clear()

# Same effect, less characters...

def clear():
    '''
    Clears the terminal screen and scroll back to present
    the user with a nice clean, new screen. Useful for managing
    menu screens in terminal applications.
    '''
    os.system('cls||echo -e \\\\033c')
```

This has the OP's desired effect. It does use the os.system() command, it could maybe be implemented using the subprocess.call().

Comment: This one works for me on Raspberry Pi. Joril's answer does not reset the cursor to the top of screen.

Comment: You might want to check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937058/clear-screen-in-shell/20247284#20247284

Comment: @Simon, your reference is not cross-platform as OP requested but instead targets Darwin devices. Yes `'clear'` works in some nix environments but not all, whereas `'cls'` is windows specific and `'echo -e \\\\033c'` works in all Bash environments

Comment: OK, sorry about that.  Admittedly I run on Windows and sometimes Ubuntu, so I don't know much about the different environments.

Comment: `echo -e` is a non-POSIX extension -- it isn't guaranteed to be supported at all, and even when your shell is 100% guaranteed to be bash it's able to be turned off (run `set -o posix; shopt -s xpg_echo`, and then `echo -e` will print `-e` on output). See [the POSIX specification for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), which explicitly recommends using `printf` instead when you need to print escape sequences.

Comment: subprocess.call() [may or may not have been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-the-terminal-in-python/26639250#comment137184291_39096404).

Answer (score 8):

A *pure* Python solution.

It does not rely on either [ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), or external commands.

Only your terminal has to have the ability to tell you how many lines are in view.

```
from shutil import get_terminal_size
print("\n" * get_terminal_size().lines, end='')
```

Python version 3.3.0 or greater.

Comment: Doesn't that leave the cursor at the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 4):

This function works in [GNOME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME) terminal because, by default, it recognizes [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). It gives you a *clean prompt* `rows_max` distance from the bottom of the terminal, but also precisely from where it was called. It gives you complete control over how much to clear.

```
def clear(rows=-1, rows_max=None, *, calling_line=True, absolute=None,
          store_max=[]):
    """clear(rows=-1, rows_max=None)
clear(0, -1) # Restore auto-determining rows_max
clear(calling_line=False) # Don't clear calling line
clear(absolute=5) # Absolutely clear out to 5 rows up"""
    from os import linesep
    if rows_max and rows_max != -1:
        store_max[:] = [rows_max, False]
    elif not store_max or store_max[1] or rows_max == -1 or absolute:
        try:
            from shutil import get_terminal_size
            columns_max, rows_max = get_terminal_size()
        except ImportError:
            columns_max, rows_max = 80, 24
        if absolute is None:
            store_max[:] = [rows_max, True]
    if store_max:
        if rows == -1:
            rows = store_max[0]
        elif isinstance(rows, float):
            rows = round(store_max[0] * rows)
        if rows > store_max[0] - 2:
            rows = store_max[0] - 2
    if absolute is None:
        s = ('\033[1A' + ' ' * 30 if calling_line else '') + linesep * rows
    else:
        s = '\033[{}A'.format(absolute + 2) + linesep
        if absolute > rows_max - 2:
            absolute = rows_max - 2
        s += (' ' * columns_max + linesep) * absolute + ' ' * columns_max
        rows = absolute
    print(s + '\033[{}A'.format(rows + 1))
```

Implementation:

```
clear() # Clear all, TRIES to automatically get terminal height
clear(800, 24) # Clear all, set 24 as terminal (max) height
clear(12) # Clear half of terminal below if 24 is its height
clear(1000) # Clear to terminal height - 2 (24 - 2)
clear(0.5) # float factor 0.0 - 1.0 of terminal height (0.5 * 24 = 12)
clear() # Clear to rows_max - 2 of user given rows_max (24 - 2)
clear(0, 14) # Clear line, reset rows_max to half of 24 (14-2)
clear(0) # Just clear the line
clear(0, -1) # Clear line, restore auto-determining rows_max
clear(calling_line=False) # Clear all, don't clear calling line
clear(absolute=5) # Absolutely clear out to 5 rows up
```

Parameters: `rows` is the number of clear text rows to add between prompt and bottom of terminal, pushing everything up. `rows_max` is the height of the terminal (or maximum clearing height) in text rows, and only needs to be set once, but it can be reset at any time. `*,` in the third parameter position means all following parameters are keyword only (e.g., clear(absolute=5)). `calling_line=True` (default) works better in Interactive mode. `calling_line=False` works better for text-based, terminal applications. `absolute` was added to try to fix glitchy gap problems in Interactive mode after reducing size of terminal, but can also be used for terminal applications. `store_max` is just for secret, "persistent" storage of `rows_max` value; don't explicitly use this parameter. (When an argument is not passed for `store_max`, changing the list contents of `store_max` changes this parameter's default value. Hence, persistent storage.)

Portability: Sorry, this doesn't work in [IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE), but it works >> *very cool* << in Interactive mode in a terminal (console) that recognizes ANSI escape sequences. I only tested this in [Ubuntu 13.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_13.10_.28Saucy_Salamander.29) (Saucy Salamander) using Python 3.3 in gnome-terminal. So I can only assume portability is dependant upon Python 3.3 (for the `shutil.get_terminal_size()` function for *best* results) and ANSI recognition. The `print(...)` function is Python 3. I also tested this with a simple, text-based, terminal [tic-tac-toe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe) game (application).

**For use in Interactive mode:** First copy and paste the `copy(...)` function in Interactive mode and see if it works for you. If so, then put the above function into a file named *clear.py*. In the terminal, start the Python interpreter, with 'python3'. Enter:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python3.3', ...
```

Now drop the clear.py file into one of the `path` directories listed so that Python can find it (don't overwrite any existing files). To easily use from now on:

```
>>> from clear import clear
>>> clear()
>>> print(clear.__doc__)
clear(rows=-1, rows_max=None)
clear(0, -1) # Restore auto-determining rows_max
clear(calling_line=False) # Don't clear calling line
clear(absolute=5) # Absolutely clear out to 5 rows up
```

**For use in a terminal application:** Put the `copy(...)` function into a file named clear.py in the same folder with your *main*.py file. Here is a working abstract (skeleton) example from a [tic-tac-toe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe) game application (run from terminal prompt: python3 *tictactoe*.py):

```
from os import linesep

class TicTacToe:
    def __init__(self):
        # Clear screen, but not calling line
        try:
            from clear import clear
            self.clear = clear
            self.clear(calling_line=False)
        except ImportError:
            self.clear = False
        self.rows = 0    # Track printed lines to clear

        # ...
        self.moves = [' '] * 9

    def do_print(self, *text, end=linesep):
        text = list(text)
        for i, v in enumerate(text[:]):
            text[i] = str(v)
        text = ' '.join(text)
        print(text, end=end)
        self.rows += text.count(linesep) + 1

    def show_board(self):
        if self.clear and self.rows:
            self.clear(absolute=self.rows)
        self.rows = 0
        self.do_print('Tic Tac Toe')
        self.do_print('''   |   |
 {6} | {7} | {8}
   |   |
-----------
   |   |
 {3} | {4} | {5}
   |   |
-----------
   |   |
 {0} | {1} | {2}
   |   |'''.format(*self.moves))

    def start(self):
        self.show_board()
        ok = input("Press <Enter> to continue...")
        self.moves = ['O', 'X'] * 4 + ['O']
        self.show_board()
        ok = input("Press <Enter> to close.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TicTacToe().start()
```

Explanation: `do_print(...)` on line 19 is a version of `print(...)` needed to keep track of how many new lines have been printed (`self.rows`). Otherwise, you would have to `self.rows += 1` all over the place where `print(...)` is called throughout the entire program. So each time the board is redrawn by calling `show_board()` the previous board is cleared out and the new board is printed exactly where it should be. Notice `self.clear(calling_line=False)` on line 9 basically pushes everything up RELATIVE to the bottom of the terminal, but does not clear the original calling line. In contrast, `self.clear(absolute=self.rows)` on line 29 absolutely clears out everything `self.rows` distance upward, rather than just pushing everything upward relative to the bottom of the terminal.

Ubuntu users with Python 3.3: Put `#!/usr/bin/env python3` on the very first line of the tictactoe.py file. Right click on the tictactoe.py file => Properties => Permissions tab => Check Execute: *Allow executing file as program*. Double click on the file => Click Run in Terminal button. If an open terminal's current directory is that of the tictactoe.py file, you can also start the file with `./tictactoe.py`.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows you can use:

```
>>> import os
>>> clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
>>> clear()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to clear your terminal when you are using a python shell. Then, you can do the following to clear the screen

```
import os
os.system('clear')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could tear through the [terminfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) database, but the functions for doing so are in `curses` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`python -c "from os import system; system('clear')"`

Comment: Please, no. Thats terrible.

Comment: well, it works. A bit aggressive though.

Comment: `system('clear')` is terrible? I disagree.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99261 - it's less terrible than win32api :)

Comment: I hope os.system fans don't write code that accepts any kind of user-entered data (i.e. the vast majority of applications)...

Comment: @allyourcode Aren't they all suggesting it in cases where the commands are fixed strings? Then we'd better not recommend removing a file in bash with `rm file` either - as someone could misunderstand it and execute `rm -rf /` as root instead.

Comment: when it's down voted to 0. i will delete it. it's interesting that the most upvoted answer is about the same thing. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `call()` function to execute terminal's commands:

```
from subprocess import call

call("clear")
```

Comment: Can you add a documentation reference to call()? I couldn't find it on the [*subprocess* page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: OK, it is on [this Python 3.8 page](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call). The former says "3.12.1".

Comment: This answer ought to be updated. But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.

Comment: `call` ***may*** have been deprecated and later removed  (my emphasis): *"For Python 3.5 or later, it is recommended that you use the* ***`run`*** *function from the subprocess module."* (from an answer to *[Retrieving the output of subprocess.call()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518)*).

Comment: [Python 3.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Table_of_versions) was released on 2015-09-13. [Python 3.8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Table_of_versions) was released on 2019-10-14.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own. This will not be dependent on your terminal, or OS type.

```
def clear(num):
    for i in range(num): print

clear(80)
print "hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to clear the screen, this is probably good enough. The problem is there's not even a 100% cross platform way of doing this across Linux versions. The problem is the implementations of the terminal all support slightly different things. I'm fairly sure that "clear" will work everywhere. But the more "complete" answer is to use the [xterm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm) control characters to move the cursor, but that requires xterm in and of itself.

Without knowing more of your problem, your solution seems good enough.

Answer (score 1):

This will clear 25 new lines:

```
def clear():
    print(' \n' * 25)

clear()
```

I use [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) with [PyDev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyDev). I like the newline solution better than the `for num in range`. The *for* loop throws warnings, while the print newline doesn't.
If you want to specify the number of newlines in the clear statement, try this variation.

```
def clear(j):
    print(' \n' * j)

clear(25)
```

Comment: 25 lines is hardly a standard today - 70 lines are more guaranteed to scroll up all the lines one will be using in a serious terminal (window's various DOS shell remakes not being considered serious, mainly due to UI limitations)

Answer (score 0):

A perhaps cheesy way to clear the screen, but one that will work on any platform I know of, is as follows:

```
for i in xrange(0,100):
    print ""
```

Comment: It will leave the cursor at the end of the window. It also leaves the possibility to scroll back to what was previously there. Might be a good thing or not. Also, you might want to put a greater number since some user could be using more than 100 lines...;)

Comment: You could also write `print ('\n' * 100)` which will work in Python 2.x and 3.x while being faster.

Comment: Does it do? Print 100 (empty) lines?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, on the interpreter command line only (not the GUI!), simply type (remember to use proper indentation with Python):

```
import os
def clear():
    os.system('cls')
```

Every time you type `clear()` on the shell (command line), it will clear the screen in your shell. If you exit the shell, then you must redo the above to do it again as you open a new Python (command line) shell.

Note: It does not matter what version of Python you are using, explicitly (2.5, 2.7, 3.3 & 3.4).

Comment: This way can be combined with platform.system() to get "Windows", "Linux" or other systems platforms info then set clear command per OS. I have mine with cls() name as follow `def cls():
    if platform.system() == "Linux":
        os.system("clear")
    elif platform.system() == "Windows":
        os.system("cls")`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in this way to make it look more like [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29):

Just create a file named .pythonstartup in the home directory and use [poke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-the-terminal-in-python/2084628#2084628) in a function.

On Linux:

```bash
echo "from subprocess import call
def clear(int=None):
    call('clear')
    if int == 0:
       exit()
clear()" >> $HOME/.pythonstartup ; export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.pythonstartup ; python
```

You can add `export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.pythonstartup` to your `./bashrc` file

Since what I care about is space; a call to the function will not display the python interpreter description at startup, but you can remove `clear()` to retain it.

Using it like a normal function should do the trick without printing the exit status:

```
>>> clear()
```

If you pass the argument 0 to the function it will clear the screen and exit successfully, so you can continue using the shell in a clean screen:

```
>>> clear(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python/2084521#2084521) is a good solution.  The problem with it is that so far it only works on Windows 10, Linux and Mac.  Yes Windows (known for it lack of ANSI support)!  This new feature was implemented on Windows 10 (and above) which includes ANSI support, although you have to enable it.  This will clear the screen in a cross platform manner:

```
import os

print ('Hello World')
os.system('') 
print ("\x1B[2J")
```

On anything below Windows 10 however it returns this:

```
[2J
```

This is due to the lack of ANSI support on previous Windows builds.  This can however, be solved using the [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) module.  This adds support for ANSI characters on Windows:

> ANSI escape character sequences have long been used to produce colored terminal text and cursor positioning on Unix and Macs. Colorama makes this work on Windows, too, by wrapping stdout, stripping ANSI sequences it finds (which would appear as gobbledygook in the output), and converting them into the appropriate win32 calls to modify the state of the terminal. On other platforms, Colorama does nothing.

So here is a cross platform method:

```
import sys

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    from colorama import init
    init()

print('Hello World')

print("\x1B[2J")
```

Or `print(chr(27) + "[2J")` used instead of `print("\x1B[2J")`.

---

@poke answer is very insecure on Windows, yes it works but it is really a hack.  A file named `cls.bat` or `cls.exe` in the same dictionary as the script will conflict with the command and execute the file instead of the command, creating a huge security hazard.

One method to minimise the risk could be to change the location of where the `cls` command is called:

```
import os
os.system('cd C:\\Windows|cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

This will change the **C**urrant **D**ictionary to `C:\Window` (backslash is important here) then execute.  `C:\Windows` is always present and needs administration permissions to write there making it a good for executing this command with minimal risk.  Another solution is to run the command through PowerShell instead of Command Prompt since it has been secured against such vulnerabilities.

There are also other methods mentioned in this question: [Clear screen in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937058/clear-screen-in-shell/18937214#18937214) which may also be of use.

Answer (score -3):

By default, `os.system("clear")`/`os.system("cls")` will return an int type as 0.
We can completely clear the screen by assigning it to a variable and deleting that.

```
def clear():
    if (os.name == 'nt'):    
        c = os.system('cls')
    else:
        c = os.system('clear')
    del c  # can also omit c totally

#clear()
```

Comment: duplicate of answer given more than 2 years ago... longer and less elegent.  See @poke answer with most votes for this question

Answer (score -6):

This works on all platforms and it does work in both Python 2 and 3.

```
def clear(number):
    for i in range(number):
        print(" ")
```

Then to clear just type `clear(numberhere)`.

Comment: Bad. For loops are slower than just `print(""*100)`. Also no need to print the space.

Comment: This is printing spaces on the terminal rather cleaning it.