# Clear the screen in python

Tags: python, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [clear terminal in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python)

How can I clear the window for all text, so that it looks like it has just been opened?

I've heard os.system("clear") works, but it didn't.

Using Python 2.6.5 on Windows 7

Comment: There's always `print '\n' * 25` ;)

Answer (score 1):

`clear` is for linux, I believe. `cls` should do the trick:

`os.system("cls")`

Answer (score 0):

`os.system('cls')`

That should work