# Cross platform way of clearing the screen in Python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [clear terminal in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python)

I have a Python script that I am targetting Windows and Linux users with -- the script runs from the command line only.

Before starting the script, I'd like to clear the screen. The best I could come up with was using the `platform` module and then calling `subprocess`.

```
>>> if platform.system() == 'Linux': # call clear
```

The same goes for Windows, where I call `cls`.

Is this good or I can do better?