# How to clear the screen in Python

Tags: python, screen

> **Possible Duplicates:** 
> [Clear the terminal in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python) 
> [How can I clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-python-interpreter-console)

I'm trying to write a program in Python, but I don't know how to clear the screen.
I use both Windows and Linux, and I use commands to clear the screen in those, but I don't know how to do it in Python.

How do I use Python to clear the screen?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466866 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432480 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970

Comment: Already asked & answered a few times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807925/cross-platform-way-of-clearing-the-screen-in-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-python-interpreter-console, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python

Comment: Linux [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop): `Ctrl+L`

Comment: There is now a simple class: pip3 install clear-screen  and then to use it:   from clear-screen import clear    and then   the method clear() will clear your shell

Comment: Note: the duplicate *"How can I clear the interpreter console?"* is tagged with [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows). And it contains *"Note: I'm running on Windows, so Ctrl + L doesn't work."*

Answer (score 301):

If you mean the screen where you have that interpreter prompt, `>>>`, you can do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in the Bash shell. Windows does not have equivalent. You can do

```
import os
os.system('cls')  # On Windows (<https://ss64.com/nt/cls.html>)
```

or

```
os.system('clear')  # On Linux / OS X
```

Comment: To avoid the 0 (`system`'s return value) being shown, use `absolutely_unused_variable = os.system("cls")` or `absolutely_unused_variable = os.system("clear")`

Comment: `_=os.system("cls")` or `_=os.system("clear")` seems much better

Comment: This answer is as close as the absolute way of not doing it as one can get. You don't need to run an entire outside process just to clear the screen - just print a number of newlines higher than the screen height:  `print ("\n" * 100) `

Comment: @jsbueno Please **please** post as answer. Please. Then tell me, so I can +1 it.

Comment: This question is closed as duplicate of the other - it can't accept new answers.

Comment: just adding hundrets of new lines is stupid because the promt is then at the bottom of the screen not at the top which is not really clearing the console but spamming things that are invisible

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically pass the string-argument so that the code is independent of the OS?

Comment: clear = os.system("cls") and no output 0

Comment: `cls = lambda: print("\033c\033[3J", end='')` and then `cls()`, or directly `print("\033c\033[3J", end='')`

Comment: The last comment is probably using [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Octal `33` is decimal `27` and hexadecimal `1B`.