# How do you print out blank lines in python?

Tags: python

I haven't been able to find out anything on this.
I would like to know how to use a function (e.g. `clear_screen`) that can print out 20 blank lines.
The last line of my program should be a call to `clear_screen`.

The start of my code is:

```
def new_line():
    print
def three_lines():
    new_line()
    new_line()
    new_line()
def nine_lines():
    three_lines()
    three_lines()
    three_lines()
print " "
nine_lines()
print " "
```

The print function works, but not with `clear_screen()` and that's what I need working.
If anyone can help me or have any suggestions, that would be great, thanks.

Comment: use curses -- part of the Python library

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810537/how-to-clear-the-screen-in-python

Comment: @drewk: Not available on Windows.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: [Console](http://effbot.org/zone/console-index.htm) then

Comment: @TimPietzcker: OK then -- the solution is boycott MS until Windows is POSIX >:-)

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a single cross-platform way I think. So instead of relying on `os.*`,  the following could work

```
print("\n"*20)
```

Comment: Thanks! The start of my code is 
def new_line():
    print

def three_lines():
    new_line()
    new_line()
    new_line()


def nine_lines():
    three_lines()
    three_lines()
    three_lines()

print " "
nine_lines()
print " "     and the print function wors, but not with def clear_screen(): and that's what I need to work?

Comment: @user2130691 please add the code to the question. I can't follow without the indents.

Comment: @Cthulhu I posted what seems to be his code in an update...

Answer (score 3):

Your `clear_screen` can be

1. `os.system` Based

   ```
   def clear_screen():
       import os
       os.system( [ 'clear', 'cls' ][ os.name == 'nt' ] )
   ```

   Works on unix and Windows.
   Source: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2084628/1931274)
2. Newline-based

   ```
   def clear_screen():
       print '\n'*19 # print creates it's own newline
   ```

---

As per your comment, it seems your code is

```
def new_line():
    print
def three_lines():
    new_line()
    new_line()
    new_line()
def nine_lines():
    three_lines()
    three_lines()
    three_lines()
print " "
nine_lines()
print " "
```

It will work and does,
**But** Why do you want to have such a long piece of code if `print '\n'*8` can do the same?

**Speed Test**
Even though you don't have a speed restriction, here's some speed stats for 100 runs each

```
os.system function took 2.49699997902 seconds.
'\n' function took 0.0160000324249 seconds.
Your function took 0.0929999351501 seconds.
```

Comment: You do realize your second 'here' points to the other answer on the same question right? ;) :D

Comment: @Cthulhu Yes, actually I was going to post that, but you posted it just before me, so I figured I'll link it to your's.