# Is there a way to clear your printed text in python?

Tags: python

I have wanted for a long time to find out how to clear something like print("example") in python, but I cant seem to find anyway or figure anything out.

```
print("Hey")
>Hey
```

Now I need to clear it, and write some new text.

```
print("How is your day?")
```

It would print.

> Hey

```
>How is your day?
```

But I want to clear the "Hey" so the user shouldnt look at both at same time, and it looks kinda messy.

Comment: Once you are wrote to`Console` you cannot erase it, when you are holding it in a buffer you may do that. [NOTE] `clear` in `linux` does not erases your written text, rather it `scrolles` up !!

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810537/how-to-clear-the-screen-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of [clear terminal in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```

Or `os.system('clear')` on unix (mac and linux). If you don't want the scroll up either, then you *can* do this:

`os.system("printf '\033c'")` should get rid of scroll back too. Something that works on all systems:

```
import os
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
```

Comment: `clear` command does not erase or remove the text from console

Comment: @SivaCn It does for me.

Comment: it also does for me(win7 py2.6)... what OS and python are you using Siva?

Comment: Yes, It clears but I can still get when I scroll up, `BUT THE QUESTION IS TO CLEAR` right ?

Comment: I'm using `cent OS`, `Ubuntu` and `Linux Mint` with `Python 2.6`, `2.7`, and `3`

Comment: @SivaCn Does my latest addition to the answer clean up the buffer?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, Its great !, I wanted it to be, Even i had the same Question for the long time, sorry for interruption, good learning. could you share some snippets regarding this ?

Comment: @Games Im pretty sure in linux without using curses the best you can do is to scroll it .. that escape sequence doesnt work on whatever linux I tested it on

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, It worked!, Could you share some snippets like this ?

Comment: @JoelMadsen Just type in the code I wrote into python, and it will clear your screen.

Comment: @JoelMadsen Awesome, if this worked for you, just give me an accept :)

Comment: Would it be possible to prevent its blinking?

Answer (score 18):

I think this is what you want to do:

> take the cursor one line up and delete the line

this can be done like using the code below

```
import sys
import time

def delete_last_line():
    "Use this function to delete the last line in the STDOUT"

    #cursor up one line
    sys.stdout.write('\x1b[1A')

    #delete last line
    sys.stdout.write('\x1b[2K')


########## FOR DEMO ################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("hello")
    print("this line will be delete after 2 seconds")
    time.sleep(2)
    delete_last_line()
####################################
```

Answer (score 4):

Small addition into `@Aniket Navlur` 's answer in order to delete multiple lines:

```py
def delete_multiple_lines(n=1):
    """Delete the last line in the STDOUT."""
    for _ in range(n):
        sys.stdout.write("\x1b[1A")  # cursor up one line
        sys.stdout.write("\x1b[2K")  # delete the last line
```

Comment: best answer and most efficient. clear screen has flickering, this one hasnt

Answer (score 2):

Well I have a temporary way:

```py
print("Hey", end="")
for i in range(4):
    print('\b', end = '')

print("How is your day?")
```

Comment: you can rewrite `print("some text",end="")` as `print(end="some text")`

Answer (score 2):

The escape character `\r` (carriage return), means "start printing from beginning of this line".
But some of operating systems use it as 'newline'.
Following would work in Linux:

```
import time
import sys
#first text
print('Hey.', end="")
#flush stdout
sys.stdout.flush()
#wait a second
time.sleep(1)
#write a carriage return and new text
print('\rHow is your day?')
```

Comment: It doesn't mean *start printing from the beginning of this line*. It's more like *return the cursor to the beginning of the current line*. Printing is not involved. Also, if the new string you want to print from the start of the line is shorter than the string already on the screen the excess chars from the old string will stay on the screen. I.e. your two string will be mixed together.