# How to write code that will delete lines in the python shell?

Tags: python, shell, menu, python-idle

I am programming in the python IDLE and have created a menu consisting of 4 lines. After the user has typed a number between 1 to 4 in the shell, I want to delete the menu and the program 
will continue to run. Is there any code I can write in the IDLE to delete the menu once it is printed in the python shell?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Take a look at ncurses, IIRC python has a slick library for it

Comment: Perhaps you can find answers here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596750/is-there-a-way-to-clear-your-printed-text-in-python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596750/is-there-a-way-to-clear-your-printed-text-in-python