# How to not print new_lines in a while loop?

Tags: python, echo

I have a while loop. The purpose of this while loop is to trivially decide if a given integer **N** exists at a given index location of **M**.

I can achieve a better space complexity if I only used one line for each request of an input. Arbitrarily giving one element at a time instead of an entire list.

```
M = 2
N = 2
index = -1

while True:

   
   print('take input: ', end = "")
   a = str(input())

   index = index + 1
   if int(a) == N:
       if index == M:
           print('yes')
           break
   if index > M:
       print('no')
       break
   if index < M:
       if int(a) == N:
           print('no')
           break
```

Unintended result

```
================= RESTART: C:\Users\User\Desktop\logspace(m).py ================
take input: 1
take input: 2
no
>>>
```

I would like the console to only do one line at a time as shown below.

```
================= RESTART: C:\Users\User\Desktop\logspace(m).py ================
take input: (Do not echo previous inputs only one integer at a time... All on one line!)
no
>>>
```

### Question

Is there any functions, modules, etc that could do this without tinkering with my console settings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to clear your printed text in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596750/is-there-a-way-to-clear-your-printed-text-in-python)

Comment: @DanielGeffen It did not delete the last line. I suspect its the Console settings.