# Rewriting the second to last printed line

Tags: python, printing

In python is there an easy way to rewrite printed line?

But I'm not talking about last printed line because for that is:

`print("text", end="\r")`

Then my last resort is using `os.system("cls")` and printing all info with changed line again.

I wanted to recreate **anaconda** downloading or **docker** build.

I know maybe it's duplicate question but I haven't found it if so my bad.

Example:

```py
text
text2
text3
```

After change:

```
text
hello_world
text3
```

It could be this code:

```
import os
print('text')
print('text2')
print('text3')
os.system('cls')
print('text')
print('hello_world')
print('text3')
```

But with more printed lines it would be quite annoying to always rewriting all lines

Maybe it is **C** magic that's my only way to describe what they have done in **anaconda** or **docker**.

Comment: For unix based operating systems you could use curses or use VT100 terminal control sequences to move around the screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to clear your printed text in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596750/is-there-a-way-to-clear-your-printed-text-in-python)