# The ironic frustration with While and Pause on Python

Tags: python, while-loop, menu, cls

Just discovered this forum and it's unbelievable how helpful its community is. Well, I have an issue trying to make a "while" loop on Python. I want the program's menu to repeat until you select Option 6 - Salir (Exit). Everything is fine at first, but after I select an option and the program prints x thing, I press enter to return to the menu or continue (just like when you use a pause on C) and get an error.

```
Juan es un empleado mexicano comun con poco salario minimo. Que quiere saber de el?  MENU 
1.Salario 
2.Sombrero 
3.Playera 
4.Pantalones 
5.Tenis 
6.Salir

Seleccione una opcion 1 El salario de Juan es  7.5

MENU 
1.Salario 
2.Sombrero 
3.Playera 
4.Pantalones 
5.Tenis 
6.Salir

Seleccione una opcion Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\joguzman\Documents\Proyectos Eclipse\Clases\src\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    opcion=int(input("\nSeleccione una opcion\n")) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I also want it to clear the screen, which doesn't happen at all. Here's my code:

```
import os class empleadoClass: #las propiedades que tendra cada empleado
    salario=7.5
    sombrero='nike'
    playera='polo'
    pantalones='patito'
    tenis='adidas'
     juanObject = empleadoClass() #'juanObjeto' esta "heredando" propiedades de empleadoClass

print ("Juan es un empleado mexicano comun con poco salario minimo. Que quiere saber de el?") opcion=1


while (opcion!=6):
    print("MENU \n1.Salario \n2.Sombrero \n3.Playera \n4.Pantalones \n5.Tenis \n6.Salir")
    opcion=int(input("\nSeleccione una opcion\n"))



    if (opcion==1):
        print ("El salario de Juan es ",juanObject.salario)
        os.system('pause>nul')
        os.system('cls')

    elif (opcion==2):
        print ("La marca del sombrero de Juan es ",juanObject.sombrero)
        os.system('pause>nul')
        os.system('cls')

    elif (opcion==3):
        print ("La marca de la playera de Juan es ",juanObject.playera)
        os.system('pause>nul')
        os.system('cls')

    elif (opcion==4):
        print ("La marca de los pantalones de Juan es ",juanObject.pantalones)
        os.system('pause>nul')
        os.system('cls')

    elif (opcion==5):
        print ("La marca de los tenis de Juan es ",juanObject.tenis)
        os.system('pause>nul')
        os.system('cls')

    elif(opcion==6):
        print ("Gracias por usar nuestro programa!")

    else:
        print ("Ingrese una opcion correcta")
        os.system('pause>nul')
        os.system('cls')
```

Thanks in advance! :D And sorry for any grammar mistakes, as you can see I'm not a native english speaker.

EDIT: It seems the code's structure got a messy when posting... Does anyone know how to solve this? :/

Comment: As for your formatting, it seems that you did a block quote (the ```""``` button) rather that code block (the ```{}``` button)

Comment: What Python version are you running? 2.x or 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler way to do a menu like this is to:

```
def print_menu():
    # print stuff here, 6 exits

while True:
    print_menu()
    try:
        choice = int(input('>>'))
        if choice == 1:
            blah
        elif choice == 2:
            more blah
        elif choice == 6:
            break
    except ValueError:
        handle_error()
```

As for clearing the screen that depends on what OS you are using and how you are running the program. See this question - [how to clear the screen in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810537/how-to-clear-the-screen-in-python)