# Run Python Script with Bash modules in Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, bash

I have a Python script and I'm trying to run it from Windows or some online Python interpreter. I would like my friend to test it but he doesn't have linux.

The conflict here is that I have modules such as "import os" in the script that is only native to the bash environment. So how can I get my friend to run my .py script in Windows?

Thanks!

Comment: You need cygwin project.

Comment: FYI: this has nothing to do with `bash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cool thing about python is that you friend should be able to run your script with little to no change(hopefully), to quote the python [os docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html)

> This module provides a portable way of using operating system
>   dependent functionality.

If your friend did have an issue you might have a another question to ask.

Comment: Okay so I downloaded Python for Windows and I tried running the script. I have everything running fine except these two commands:
os.system ("clear")
os.system ("sleep 2")
Which is why I think it's related to bash because those are bash commands...

Comment: Found the solution! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810537/how-to-clear-the-screen-in-python
I had to change the "clear" to "cls" in the script for it to work on windows. Thanks all!