# Python: Clear Output

Tags: python

I'm looking for a method to clear python output with "replit - clear()" and "IPython.display - clear display()".

However, I encountered an error as per the attached screenshot. Can some one help me on this?

[image: replit - clear() - error]

[image: IPython.display - clear display()- not working]

Would appreciate if can help me on this.

Thanks.

---

Output of `pip --version`, `python --version`, `python3 --version`, `which python` and `whereis python`:

```
pip 19.1.1 from /Users/weison/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip

(python 3.7)

Python 3.7.3

Python 3.9.1

/Users/weison/anaconda3/bin/python

/usr/bin/python
```

Executing `python -m pip install -U requests` in the command prompt.

[image: Prompted Warning]

Code:

```
from replit import clear
  

input('please enter you name:') 

clear()
print('hello')
```

Output:

```
Warning: REPLIT_DB_URL does not exist, are we running on repl.it? Database will not function.

please enter you name:weison

[H[2Jhello
```

Comment: The [second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjIZ0.png) doesn't show us your `clear_output()` function's code - please attach that in order to provide the minimum reproducible code to replicate the issue.

Comment: Regardless, this is a duplicate issue as per [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4810595/5568675). Please google for a solution before posting a new question.

Comment: tried on the alternative method:
##
import os

name = input ("Please enter your name: ")

os.system('clear')

print (f"Hello {name}, how are you?")
##
Output:
Please enter your name: weison
Hello weison, how are you
##
This is different with what i expected as i expect first will input name then clear screen, print the next.

Comment: @Dbercules He cannot provide the sources as he didn't write IPython himself ! But you can find it [on github](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/af130c3f7146b1c908fc4ca4111ad7d37c6593ed/IPython/core/display_functions.py#L353)

Comment: Some readers might be interested to know that while Python does not have a standard method for clearing the terminal, it's been [heavily discussed](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-ideas@python.org/thread/EWQ2BOL3WVZAU2V2MT3HLXN3AEBHANNZ/#EWQ2BOL3WVZAU2V2MT3HLXN3AEBHANNZ) on the python-ideas mailing list in [multiple threads](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-ideas@python.org/thread/N2G5MDPST6IMUQCK6LLAUOVIJIOOC2XJ/#HM5DI4Z7ZLPXNITEQNJPHSCIM4DEORAD).

Comment: @Programmer There is nothing stopping new posters from looking up the docs or source code behind functions they're using as it seems you're suggesting. We should be enabling them to be better problem solvers, and not simply providing a solution provided elsewhere numerous times before. All it takes is the encouragement of a google search.

Comment: @Dbercules hi mate, don't get me wrong. I already tried all the method posted in forum or available in google but still cant resolved my issue and hence ask help here. Btw, thanks for your comment and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

i think there’s no built-in keyword or function/method to clear the screen. So, we do it on you own.
you can do this

```
from os import system, name 
def clear(): 
  
    # for windows 
    if name == 'nt': 
        _ = system('cls') 
    # for mac and linux
    else: 
        _ = system('clear') 
  

print('please enter you name') 

clear()
print('hellow')
```

you can't use us i python display to clear console ,ipython is an interactive shell built with python.

> The IPython Notebook is now known as the Jupyter Notebook. It is an
> interactive computational environment, in which you can combine code
> execution, rich text, mathematics, plots and rich media. For more
> details on the Jupyter Notebook

Comment: hi Belhadjer Samir, I run the method above but the output still show first line without clearing the first print . im stuck now.

Comment: wich operating system you are using ?

Comment: i run it on both window and mac.. having the same output and result
Window 10
Mac OS Big Sur

Comment: the program will execute the command line to clear console it will not realy remove the first print from output if you scrol up you will see the first print

Comment: can share me the output screenshot after you run the code? and i can compare it.

Answer (score -1):

The replit method does not work, because it's missing a module which you can easily install by executing `python -m pip install -U requests` in the command prompt. The IPython one does work - it doesn't throw an error, only as far as i can see it doesn't clear the output ... And if then it always doesn't work, you can use `print("\033c", end='')` to clear the python console.

Comment: hi Programmer, i follow your instruction install executing pip install -U requests .. yet the result still having the same error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Comment: @TANWEISON Please post the output of `pip --version`, `python --version`, `python3 --version`, `which python` and `whereis python`.

Comment: the output as below:
pip 19.1.1 from /Users/weison/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
Python 3.7.3
Python 3.9.1
/Users/weison/anaconda3/bin/python
/usr/bin/python

Comment: ok, then in IPython you are using Python 3.7 as one can see on the screenshot of the error, ad pip uses Python 3.9. pip using Python 3.9 will install the modules into the module folder of Python 3.9, but Python 3.7, the one you are using in IPython, looks only in its own folder. Thats why it didnt help to run pip like i suggested. I edited my answer, try the new command please

Comment: executed the shared pip. but promoted warning now. have edited the post with screenshot and warning message

Comment: @TANWEISON dont know how to fix this ... But you wont need that database just for clearing the terminal, i think.

Comment: no worries, thanks for the guide. Appreciated.

Comment: @TANWEISON i added another method for clearing the python console. if my answer helped you, accept it please.

Comment: it works the same.. nothing happen to clear the output..

Comment: @TANWEISON well, maybe your IPython console just doesn't support clearing. In all cases, i have no further ideas, sorry ...

Comment: thanks for you patience and all the info share.

Comment: @TANWEISON but you could try to open the python interpreter in a normal command prompt, and execute `print("\033c", end='')` there. If that works, you know the IPython shell jsut doesn't support clearing. For the IPython prompt you can use `print("\n" * 100)` (printing 100 newlines is guaranteed to work, and guaranteed to clear the screen)