# Clear screen in shell

Tags: python, shell

How do you clear the screen in shell?

I've seen ways like:

```py
import os
os.system('cls')
```

This just opens the Windows cmd, clears the screen and closes but
I want the shell window to be cleared.

I'm using version 3.3.2 of Python.

Comment: Shell = the Python shell? Prompt `>>>`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

For macOS/OS X, you can use the subprocess module and call 'cls' from the shell:

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.call('cls', shell=True)
```

To prevent '0' from showing on top of the window, replace the 2nd line with:

```
tmp = sp.call('cls', shell=True)
```

For Linux, you must replace `cls` command with `clear`

```
tmp = sp.call('clear', shell=True)
```

Comment: I am using Mac OS X, and I tried this `import subprocess as sp
sp.call('clear',shell=True)` which works, except there is a `0` at the top of the terminal window.

Comment: 0 is the return value of the 'cls' command call from shell.
i edited the answer to get rid of that as well, by simply storing that value in a variable.

Comment: Try this `ctrl+L`

Comment: That works on the command line. Question was how to do it in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the solution,  I was missing shell=True.  to prevent the 0 from showing up you can also add a semicolon to the end of the statement.

``sp.call('cls', shell=True);``

Answer (score 92):

Use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

It works for all shells, e.g., Python, [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29), [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL), [MATLAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), etc.

Comment: Unfortunately does not work on Windows including the new cmd in Windows10

Comment: When using subprocess for automation this approach do not work.

Comment: Re *"works for all shells"*: What is the assumption? For Unix-like shells?

Comment: Does it really work in MATLAB?

Answer (score 69):

```
import os

os.system('cls')  # For Windows
os.system('clear')  # For Linux/OS X
```

Comment: Also, `os.system('clear')` for Mac OS X terminals (confirmed to work with the default shell, `bash`, and also for `csh`).

Comment: You can also define a function to run this, like: def cls(): os.system('cls') (hit enter twice). Then you can just type cls() to clear the screen.

Comment: The question was about how to do this in the shell.

Comment: @KyleDelaney while inefficient, it works in the shell. Also many people found this useful because that's what they were looking for.

Answer (score 15):

Here are some options that you can use on Windows

The first option:

```
import os
cls = lambda: os.system('cls')

>>> cls()
```

The second option:

```
cls = lambda: print('\n' * 100)

>>> cls()
```

The third option if you are in the Python [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) window:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: Thanks.  Ctrl + L works fine on Windows (Anaconda Shell)

Answer (score 12):

The sort of thing that you are looking for is to be found in the [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) module.

I.e.,

```
import curses  # Get the module
stdscr = curses.initscr()  # Initialise it
stdscr.clear()  # Clear the screen
```

## Important Note

The important thing to remember is before any exit, you need to reset the terminal to a normal mode. This can be done with the following lines:

```
curses.nocbreak()
stdscr.keypad(0)
curses.echo()
curses.endwin()
```

If you don't, you will get all sort of strange behaviour.  To ensure that this is always done, I would suggest using the *atexit* module. Something like:

```
import atexit

@atexit.register
def goodbye():
    """ Reset terminal from curses mode on exit """
    curses.nocbreak()
    if stdscr:
        stdscr.keypad(0)
    curses.echo()
    curses.endwin()
```

It will probably do nicely.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: I'm running Mac OS X 10.7.5 and iTerm 2 for my terminal. Using Python2.7, the `stdscr = curses.initscr()` works to clear the screen, and the `stdscr.clear()` does nothing. Using Python3.4, the `stdscr = curses.initscr()` does clear the screen, but takes away the terminal's ability to process newlines. When I press enter repeatedly, it gives the following: `>>> >>> >>> >>> ` and so on. I can still type commands, but they don't show up. Also, this behavior persists even when I `exit()` Python.
AVOID USE!

Comment: @jvriesem the curses module has been in use for a long time and has been used by a lot of people - I would suggest that you see if you can replicate the behaviour in a short, (20 lines or so), example and either post it as a stack overflow question or on the developer mailing list.

Comment: Good idea -- that's a better response than my "AVOID USE!" statement. 
The first two lines of this answer were the two lines that replicate the problem for me. Do you know if there's any reason the `curses` module might have compatibility issues (Windows vs. Mac vs. Linux)? I can confirm that this issue happens on two different Mac terminals, at least. The behavior persists in BASH but not CSH. Hmm.... Do you think I should contact the curses developer, the shell developer, or just ask the SO community? Thanks again!

Comment: @jvriesem - I have updated my answer to include how to reset your terminal to standard mode once you have finished, including on any exit.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to being an all-around great CLI library, `click` also provides a platform-agnostic [`clear()`](http://click.pocoo.org/6/utils/#screen-clearing) function:

```py
import click
click.clear()
```

Answer (score 7):

This function works in any OS (Unix, Linux, macOS, and Windows)

**Python 2 and Python 3**

```
import platform    # For getting the operating system name
import subprocess  # For executing a shell command

def clear_screen():
    """
    Clears the terminal screen.
    """

    # The clear command, as function of the OS
    command = "cls" if platform.system().lower()=="windows" else "clear"

    # Action
    return subprocess.call(command) == 0
```

In Windows, the command is `cls`, in unix-like systems the command is `clear`.
`platform.system()` returns the platform name. For example, `'Darwin'` for macOS.
`subprocess.call()` performs a system call. For example, `subprocess.call(['ls','-l'])`

Answer (score 6):

An easier way to clear a screen while in the Python shell is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> though it works for the shell as well as other programs.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a Linux terminal to access Python, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> is the best solution to clear the screen.

Answer (score 4):

I am using a class that just uses one of the above methods behind the scenes... I noticed it works on Windows and Linux... I like using it though because it's easier to type clear() instead of system('clear') or os.system('clear')

```
pip3 install clear-screen

from clear_screen import clear
```

and then when you want to clear the shell:

```
clear()
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Windows 10 and pyhton3.5, I have tested many codes and nothing helped me more than this:

First define a simple function. This function will print 50 newlines; (the number 50 will depend on how many lines you can see on your screen, so you can change this number)

```
def cls(): print ("\n" * 50)
```

Then just call it as many times as you want or need:

```
cls()
```

Comment: None of the ready built command ideas worked for me. creating this, my own function of course did.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than importing all of curses or shelling out just to get one control character, you can simply use (on Linux/macOS):

```
print(chr(27) + "[2J")
```

(Source: [Clear terminal in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python))

Answer (score 2):

Module [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) allows you to call "cls" for Shell.

```
import subprocess

cls = subprocess.call('cls', shell=True)
```

That's as simple as I can make it.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> works fine in OS X to clear the screen.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to clear only the scrollback buffer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import curses
stdscr = curses.initscr()
stdscr.clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the Windows or Linux OS

   ```python
   import os

   os.system('cls')
   os.system('clear')
   ```
2. You can use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module

   ```python
   import subprocess as sp

   x = sp.call('cls', shell=True)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`os.system('cls')` works fine when I open them. It opens in cmd style.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to make your very own `cls` or `clear` command that will work without explicitly calling any function!

We'll take advantage of the fact that the python console calls `repr()` to display objects on screen. This is especially useful if you have your own customized python shell (with the `-i` option for example) and you have a pre-loading script for it. This is what you need:

```
import os
class ScreenCleaner:
    def __repr__(self):
        os.system('cls')  # This actually clears the screen
        return ''  # Because that's what repr() likes

cls = ScreenCleaner()
```

Use `clear` instead of `cls` if you're on Linux (in both the `os` command and the variable name)!

Now if you just write `cls` or `clear` in the console, it will clear it! Not even `cls()` or `clear()`—just the raw variable. This is because Python will call `repr(cls)` to print it out, which will in turn trigger our `__repr__` function.

Let's test it out:

```
>>> df;sag
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'df' is not defined
>>> sglknas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sglknas' is not defined
>>> lksnldn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'lksnldn' is not defined
>>> cls
```

And the screen is clear!

To clarify, the code above needs to either be imported in the console like this

```python
from somefile import cls
```

Or preloaded directly with something like:

```
python -i my_pre_loaded_classes.py
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the best way:

```
>>>import os
>>>def cls(): os.system('cls')
>>>cls()
```

Comment: I don't really see how your answer improves on any of the answers already given in previous years.

Comment: Those who need it will see. I have no need for improvement bro. thanks, bro.

Comment: he wasnt talking about improving yóur answer. He stated that your answer isn't useful, because someone else has already given the same one.

Answer (score 0):

**For the Python IDLE 3.8.1 you can restart the Shell**

CTRL + F6

On the menu Click on the Shell menu.
Then click on the Restart Shell option.