# Python - Fastest way to clear the screen?

Tags: python, cmd, line, screen

What would the fastest way to clear the screen, be?

I've tried many solutions, they seem to work, however, I need the fastest way. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

The screen, in my case, is a command prompt.

I've edited my question for better understandings.

Any help welcomed :)

Comment: Have you run any timeits or other measures to see which is fastest? There are a [number of answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937058/python-clear-screen-in-shell) for this question and it should not be hard for you to test them (and would avoid any variance between systems affecting the runtimes)

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I didn't see that page :)

Comment: How fast does it need to be?

Comment: It sounds like you might be interested in a library like [UniCurses](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/UniCurses) that lets you manipulate the terminal more directly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it ;)

Answer (score 4):

One portable solution could be:

```
def clear_sceen():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

Another possible way would be using:

```
print(chr(27) + "[2J")
```

Although this one wouldn't be really a portable solution

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. :)

however, I said in my post, That I've used os.system('cls') and it was a bit slow :) I appreciate your answer though ;D

Comment: @CoolqB Edited my answer