# Python Delete and Print Same Line

Tags: python

I am working on making a count down time for a class in school and when I print it it looks like this:

```
0 months 14 days 10 hours 3 min 24seconds
0 months 14 days 10 hours 3 min 23seconds
0 months 14 days 10 hours 3 min 22seconds
0 months 14 days 10 hours 3 min 21seconds
```

is there any way to make it every time it prints a line, it deletes it so it looks like the numbers are changing something like this:

```
0 months 14 days 10 hours 3 min 24seconds
```

and then on the same line:

```
0 months 14 days 10 hours 3 min 23seconds
```

I realize there are a million answers online, but none of them seem work for my computer. I am using a Mac running OS X Yosemite with python 3.5.3. If anybody finds anything that works here please let me know.

Comment: @EricDuminil I am using Mac running OS X Yosemite and Python 3.5.3

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the screen between prints. (Here's an example on Windows) :

```
import os
from time import sleep
cls = lambda: os.system('cls')

for i in range(1000):
    print i
    sleep(1)
    cls()
```

For other systems, see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937058/clear-screen-in-shell).

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example of how you can do it. You would have to modify it according to your needs.

```
from time import sleep

for i in range(10):
    print('\r{}'.format(i), end="")
    sleep(0.5)
```