# Python clear the screen

Tags: python, macos, screenshot

I am still trying to make my quiz, but I want to enter a clear the screen code for my questions. So, after researching, I found a code that works, but it puts my questions way to the bottom of the screen. Here is a screenshot I took:

[image: The Image is below]

here is a example of the clear the screen code I found:

```
print "\n" * 40
```

So I tried changing the "40" To "20" but there was no effects. I am operating on Mac so the

```
import os
os.system('blahblah')
```

does not work. Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [clear terminal in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @pNre noted, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python) shows you how to do this with ASCI escape sequences.

If you'd like to do this using the `os` module, then on Mac the command is `clear`.

```
import os
os.system('clear')
```

Note: The fact that you are on a Mac does not mean `os.system('blahblah')` will not work. It is more likely the command you are passing to `os.system` was erroneous.

See answer below for how to do this on Windows/Linux.

Answer (score 3):

**This function works in any OS (Unix, Linux, OS X, and Windows)**
**Python 2 and Python 3**

```
from platform   import system as system_name  # Returns the system/OS name
from subprocess import call   as system_call  # Execute a shell command

def clear_screen():
    """
    Clears the terminal screen.
    """
    
    # Clear screen command as function of OS
    command = 'cls' if system_name().lower().startswith('win') else 'clear'

    # Action
    system_call([command])
```

In windows the command is `cls`, in unix-like systems the command is `clear`.
`platform.system()` returns the platform name. Ex. `'Darwin'` in macOS.
`subprocess.call()` performs a system call. Ex. `subprocess.call(['ls','-l'])`

Comment: I am getting "win32" instead of "windows" what does that mean ?? and why

Comment: I do not own a Windows computer, however I assume your output is including the API version (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API#Versions).
I changed the code so that it works with that output.

Answer (score 2):

Can be done by subprocess

```
import subprocess as sp

clear_the_screen = sp.call('cls', shell=True) # Windows <br>
clear_the_screen = sp.call('clear', shell=True) # Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

Best OSX solution for Python (No need to import any modules), simply do:

```
print("\033c\033[3J")
```

Or in Terminal for bash/shell script use:

```
echo -n "\033c\033[3J"
```

Or:

```
printf "\033c\033[3J"
```

Do **NOT** use `clear` command!

In OSX if you use command: `clear` then you will still be able to scroll back in Terminal window so it will not help to save/clear memory.