# How to clear python console (i.e. Ctrl+L command line equivalent)

Tags: python, console

OS = Linux

```
[boris@E7440-DELL ~]$ uname -a
Linux E7440-DELL 3.17.4-200.fc20.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 21 23:26:41 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

From python console (Spyder 2.2.4, Python 2.7.5 64bits, Qt 4.8.5) it is seen as:

```
>>> import os
>>> print(os.name)
posix
```

I'm trying to find out a way to clear python console. Not just any solution is suitable, but it must be exactly same result as pressing Ctrl+L.

From other threads I have already tried several options:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('clear')
256

>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call("clear", shell=True)
1

>>> print '\n'*1000
```

As you can see neither `os.system('clear')` nor `subprocess.call("clear", shell=True)` produce desired result. They just output a value (256 or 1 respectively).
`print '\n'*1000` is so far closest the desired outcome. However, there are two issues with it:

1. the cursor is not at the top of the screen (as Ctrl+L does), but it stays at the bottom, so all new lines printed by my code are being scrolled upwards, which makes it impossible to read.
2. the visual experience is highly dependent on the value, so in order to make it somewhat readable I have to use `print '\n'*100000` instead

Does anyone know the right solution, the one that can really do Ctrl+L from the command line? (yes I am using linux, and I have no interest in windows solutions)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear python interpreter console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-python-interpreter-console) and [clear terminal in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python)

Comment: `os.system("clear")` worked for me. What OS are you using?

Comment: He mentioned his OS in last line (linux). Most important information should be in first line

Comment: Have you tried `print '\x0c'`?

Comment: When you say "Python console" do you mean just running `python` from a command prompt? Or are you using something like Idle?

Comment: With "python console" I mean the Console tab of the Python interpreter in Spyder.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
os.system('tput reset')
```

To hide the return value, use:

```
variable = os.system('tput reset')
```

Comment: As I already mentioned above it does not work, it just outputs a value 256

Comment: You can also try 
    "os.system('tput reset')"
To hide the return value, use "variable = os.system('tput reset')"

Comment: Tried, but again nothing happens. Only the output value is changed, now it is 0.