# Clear terminal without creating empty space in python

Tags: macos, python-3.x

I have found no method of clearing the terminal window from within a python script that does so without creating a huge empty space above the screen. I am writing a script that needs to periodically update the screen and doing so using `os.system("clear")` makes for a long scroll to see wherever you were before running the script. [edit] `os.system("tput reset")` also does this [/edit]

Edit: I forgot to mention which operating system I'm using, it's Mac OS X 10.10.

To clarify, I **am not** looking for just any way to clear the screen, I am looking for a way that *is not functionally equivalent to hitting enter a bunch of times.* (e.g. `print("\n\n\n\n\n\n...")`)

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "huge empty space above the screen"?  Isn't that what you want, if you are going to clear the screen?

Comment: Sounds like you should use the [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) library.

Comment: How do you send a CMD+k through python script?

Answer (score 1):

"""
You can try:

```
os.system('tput reset')
```

To hide the return value, use:

```
variable = os.system('tput reset')
```

"""

as seen :: [How to clear python console (i.e. Ctrl+L command line equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420880/how-to-clear-python-console-i-e-ctrll-command-line-equivalent)

Or the answer to a similar question I actually asked a while back...

"""
What you're looking for is:

```
print("{}/100".format(k), "\r", end="")
```

\r is carriage return, which returns the cursor to the beginning of the line. In effect, whatever is printed will overwrite the previous printed text. end="" is to prevent \n after printing (to stay on the same line).

In Python 2, the same can be achieved with:

```
print "{}/100".format(k), "\r",
```

"""
as seen :: [Unprint a line on the console in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203228/unprint-a-line-on-the-console-in-python)

Comment: I am looking for a way that is not functionally equivalent to hitting enter a bunch of times. Thanks for the effort though.