# clear terminal (and history!) in Python

Tags: python, terminal

This is *almost* a duplicate of [clear terminal in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python), but not quite.

That question reads: Does any standard "comes with batteries" method exist to clear the terminal screen from a python script, or do I have to go curses (the libraries, not the words) ?

All of the responses there result in what happens when you enter `clear` on your terminal - everything on your screen disappears except for an empty command line at the very top. But, if you'd like, you can scroll back up to see what you were doing earlier.

I'm looking for a way to do this, but to not allow the user to scroll back up. It's the equivalent of what `command+K` does on macOS.

The application is a multiplayer card game, and I don't want a player to be able to scroll back up to see another player's hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) from the standard library `subprocess` module to send the `reset` command to the terminal which will reinitialize the terminal and in effect do something similar to `clear` but also clear the scrollback history.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('reset')
```

Alternatively, I have learned from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/25079/396191), that you can use the command `tput reset` instead, which will clear the terminal instantly, whereas with `reset` alone you will experience a slight delay. This can also be called with `subprocess.call()` as follows:

```
subprocess.call(['tput', 'reset'])
```

For more info on the `reset` command, do:

```
$ man reset
```

For more info on the `subprocess` module, see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

I have tested both of these on Ubuntu, but hopefully the will work on OSX/macOS as well. If not, perhaps you can use `subprocess` combined with [this solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/31887), but I am unable to test that.

Answer (score 2):

Python comes with a `curses` module, which basically lets you implement a GUI of sorts on a text screen.  Players would not be able to scroll back to previous output, unless you intentionally implemented a scrolling text window.  The terminal's scrollback feature doesn't do anything in a curses application, because nothing is actually scrolling off the screen - it's being overwritten instead.