# Print updating variable in the same line

Tags: python

What I'm trying to code is pretty simple:

I want to print an iteration variable, but I don't want all the lines printed for each loop, I want that will update the previous one.

Example:

```
for i in range(0,2000):
   print 'number is %d', %i
```

Wrong result:

```
number is 0
number is 1
number is 2
number is 3
number is 4
number is 5
number is 6
...
...
```

What I want is:

```
number is 0
```

At the second iteration:

```
number is 1 `(it will replace 0 and I don't want the previous 0 anymore).`
```

It will be something like updating percentage of something in only one line.

Does a function exist for it in Python?

Comment: FYI: you use # to write comments in python

Answer (score 4):

This will do the trick, and update every 1 second:

```
import sys
import time

for i in range(0,2000):
    sys.stdout.write('\rnumber is %d' %i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called the `Carriage Return`, or `\r`

Use:

```
for i in range(0,2000):
    print "number is %d       \r" %i,
```

The spaces will keep the line clear from prior output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python#answer-2084560) thread on clearing the terminal, or something from the one that [fuglede](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5085211/fuglede) posted as duplicated.

The following code worked fine for me in a mac, but if you remove the time.sleep() it will just run so fast that you wont even see the prints.

```
import time, sys

for i in range(0, 20):
    print 'Number is: %d' % i
    time.sleep(.1)
    sys.stderr.write("\x1b[2J\x1b[H")
```