# python keypress simple game

Tags: python, keypress

I would like to see on screen a sign, e.x might be (hash) '#'. Sign will have some starting position, let's say (0, 0). I would like to see sign moving right if I press right arrow, left if I press left arrow, etc.
So far my code looks like this, and it works for reading pos, but I want to add some kind of "animation" so I can see sign is moving on the screen:

**!Update:** Just to give u a clue, I created "icon" and now when u press right or left, icon moves in desired direction.

```
from msvcrt import getch

icon = chr(254)
pos = [0, 0]
t = []
def fright():
    global pos
    pos[0] += 1
    print ' ' * pos[0], 
    print(icon) 

def fleft():
    global pos 
    pos[0] -= 1
    print ' ' * pos[0], 
    print(icon) 

def fup():
    global pos
    pos[1] += 1

def fdown():
    global pos
    pos[1] -= 1

def appendTab():
    global pos, t
    t.append(pos)

while True:
    print'Distance from zero: ', pos    
    key = ord(getch())

    if key == 27: #ESC
        break
    elif key == 13: #Enter
        print('selected')
        appendTab()
    elif key == 32: #Space, just a small test - skip this line
        print('jump')
        print(t)
    elif key == 224: #Special keys (arrows, f keys, ins, del, etc.)
        key = ord(getch())
        if key == 80: #Down arrow
            print('down')
            fdown()
        elif key == 72: #Up arrow
            print('up')
            fup()
        elif key == 75: #Left arrow
            print('left')
            fleft()
        elif key == 77: #Right arrow
            print('right')
            fright()
```

Comment: from msvcrt import getch : It appears to me you are using your own library. Please provide it.

Comment: @user7185318 [msvcrt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getch) is part of the standard library.

Comment: @skrx : Thanks, im using Linux and so I havent got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a list of lists that serves as the map and set the cell of the player to `'#'`. Then just print the map and if the player moves, clear the command-line/terminal with [`os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2084628/6220679) and print the updated map.

```
import os
from msvcrt import getch

pos = [0, 0]
# The map is a 2D list filled with '-'.
gamemap = [['-'] * 5 for _ in range(7)]
# Insert the player.
gamemap[pos[1]][pos[0]] = '#'

while True:
    print('Distance from zero: ', pos    )
    key = ord(getch())

    if key == 27: #ESC
        break
    elif key == 224: #Special keys (arrows, f keys, ins, del, etc.)
        key = ord(getch())
        if key in (80, 72, 75, 77):
            # Clear previous tile if player moves.
            gamemap[pos[1]][pos[0]] = '-'
        if key == 80: #Down arrow
            pos[1] += 1
        elif key == 72: #Up arrow
            pos[1] -= 1
        elif key == 75: #Left arrow
            pos[0] -= 1
        elif key == 77: #Right arrow
            pos[0] += 1

    print('clear')
    # Clear the command-line/terminal.
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    # Set the player to the new pos.
    gamemap[pos[1]][pos[0]] = '#'
    # Print the map.
    for row in gamemap:
        for tile in row:
            print(tile, end='')
        print()
```

Comment: You still have to add code to prevent the game from crashing if the player leaves the map.

Comment: You can also take a look at [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) and if you want to create more sophisticated roguelikes [libtcod](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Complete_Roguelike_Tutorial,_using_python%2Blibtcod) (Python 2 only). On Windows you have to download curses (as a wheel file) from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses.