# Is there a way to programmatically clear the terminal across platforms in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

Long-time lurker, first time asker.

Is there a way to automatically clear the terminal in Python 3 regardless of what platform the app is being used in?

I've come across the following (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python/2084560#2084560?newreg=660f6f0ce06149e8a5e7027e96543504)) which utilises ANSI escape codes:

```
import sys
sys.stderr.write("\x1b[2J\x1b[H")
```

But for it to work cross-platform it requires the colorama module which appears to only work on python 2.7.

For context I'm learning Python by building a game of battleships, but after each guess I want to be able to clear the screen and re-print the board.

Any help is appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: in this case you can as well output a hundred of newlines and it'll be simpler and 100% cross-platform.

Comment: Yeah I've seen that approach as well - it just doesn't look very tidy if the cursor isn't replaced at the top of the terminal. I guess it's going to be a trade-off.

Comment: Hello @SeanColey!
Did you try my answer?

Comment: @SeanColey Hello? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a single snippet for all the platforms:

```
import subprocess
clear = lambda: subprocess.call('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')
clear()
```

Same idea but with a spoon of syntactic sugar:

```
import subprocess   
clear = lambda: subprocess.call('cls||clear', shell=True)
clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know of this method

```
import os
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
clear()
```

I'm not sure if it works with other platforms, but it's working in windows python 3.x

```
import os
clear = lambda: os.system('clear')
clear()
```

That might work for linux and OS X, but I can't test.

Comment: I think this has already been dealt with here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python The simple answer is that there is not perfect, cross-platform way to do this other than output a heap of newline characters. However, there are techniques that will work on most common platforms.

Comment: Yeah that's the answer I linked in my original post. The answer given could be made cross-platform by use of the colorama module (which converted ANSI escapes for windows), but it only works on python 2.7. This is probably the best option for now.

Comment: When I try this in OS X it gives me the error 'TERM environment variable not set'. Ideas?

Comment: Check also my answer, @KevinBoone