# how to clear a running file on python

Tags: python

I am making a game where 9 words will be shown. After 30 seconds another set of 9 words will appear but with one word replaced. The aim of the game is to find which word was replaced. My question is how do I present the new set of words by clearing everything else on the file that is running. All I could think of was printing \n * 1000 which is not accurate as the player can just scroll up. Is there any alternate way?

Comment: If you need the code, please ask.

Comment: Perhaps you can try clearing the console by using the `os` package? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python#2084628

Comment: We shouldn't ask you for the code, you should provide the relevant parts of the code by *default*, unless you intentionally want your question to be *less* clear, that is ;)

Comment: I have used many types of os packages including os.system("cls") but it still does not work.