# How to clean the terminal screen in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

How can I clear/clean entire terminal screen/window of Python 3?

My aim is to:

1. Print 5 lines in terminal/output screen window in Python3
2. Clean the entire output screen
3. Print 3 lines in the screen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
os.system('cls') # on windows
```

or

```
os.system('clear') # on linux / os x
```

You can use these two for the clear screen in python 3