# How to detect window resize in Python

Tags: python, text-alignment, text-processing

How do you see if the window has been resized? I start in full screen, but if I change so it fits half of my screen, all my text gets mixed up.

Here is my code:

```py
# Import os
import os

# Create function called title that prints the title screen
def title():
    print('@------------------------------------------------------------------------------------@'.center(os.get_terminal_size().columns), end='')
    print('|                                                                                    |'.center(os.get_terminal_size().columns), end='')
    print('|                                      |PyTerm v0.1.7|                               |'.center(os.get_terminal_size().columns), end='')
    print('|                                                                                    |'.center(os.get_terminal_size().columns), end='')
    print('@------------------------------------------------------------------------------------@'.center(os.get_terminal_size().columns), end='')

# Call the function
title()
```

Once I run it, the text gets aligned, but when I go into fullscreen, they get all over the place. Is there a way to fix this? Can I somehow sense when the user resizes the window? I'm on Windows 10, using Python 3.1.9. Running it with py ( `C:\Windows\py.exe` )

This is what it looks like when I run it:
[image: Before picture]

Here is it when I go into fullscreen:
[image: After picture]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Windows machine to test on, but one possibility would be to redraw the console in a loop:

1. Clear the current screen (see: [Clear terminal in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python))
2. Run the `title` function
3. Wait for a little while

If the user resizes the screen, the resized value of the `offset` variable should be set to the new size.

```py
import os
import time


def title(offset_value):
    print('@------------------------------------------------------------------------------------@'.center(offset_value), end='')
    print('|                                                                                    |'.center(offset_value), end='')
    print('|                                      |PyTerm v0.1.7|                               |'.center(offset_value), end='')
    print('|                                                                                    |'.center(offset_value), end='')
    print('@------------------------------------------------------------------------------------@'.center(offset_value))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    while True:

        # Clear the terminal
        # See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

        # Redraw the screen
        offset = os.get_terminal_size().columns
        title(offset)

        # Wait for a bit
        time.sleep(1)
```