# Clearing terminal probelm python

Tags: python

[image]

i was using the following code to clear my terminal:

```
import os
import sys
clear=lambda:os.system('cls')
clear()
```

but instead of clearing the terminal, it output a question mark. Why? and how do i actually clear the terminal. Using python 3.9

Comment: You can find your answer in [clear-terminal-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python).

Comment: What do you get when you try some other CMD commands (`dir` for example)? Do they work as expected? If you try a garbage command do you get the standard `'aaaa' is not recognized as an internal or external command...`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using cmd. This command should only work for the normal terminal.