# how to get rid of the extra text that appear in the terminal of Vs code?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I tried my best to play with the "settings. json" file but nothing worked. I don't know how to get rid of this path so that the terminal looks clean and I can only focus on the outcome.

[path of the program that is currently running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3JgB.png)

Comment: what did you "play" with exactly ?  and what outcome are you expecting ?

Comment: go to the correct directory in the terminal and type the command yourself or create a keybinding that types the command for you, or a task

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't remove this path, as it is just the exact path to the file that python should execute.
You can try to tackle this problem from Python and just add `os.system` inside your code to clear console as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44591228/12444149).

Comment: Can it be removed from windows CMD, outside vs code?

Comment: Yes it executes the command in a console that is used by Python so provided with correct clear method it will work everywhere.