How to conditionally clear script output after execution?
I want to build/provide a wrapper for scripts with output necessary only while the script is being executed, but which should conditionally be cleaned up after script execution.
E.g. (only an example, I'm not talking about Docker)
docker build <ARGS>

can be quite verbose even when executed from cache. You also don't want to hide the output while its running generally, because then the user doesn't see what's going on.
You could use screen and run
screen docker build <ARGS>

Now you can see the output while docker build is running, and it hides after script termination. But now you have a dependency to screen and you also don't see erroneous output in case something goes wrong.
Is there a cheap (in terms of dependencies) way in Python or Bash to remove the output of a script after execution (as with screen but without extra dependencies) or (even better) do it conditionally?
(Note: I don't want to clear the whole screen of course, only what the output of the wrapped script)
To shed some lite on the use case: as in modern tools like pipenv, npm, cargo, docker-build I want to keep the user informed about an ongoing process while only errors should stay after the script terminated.
So the ideal behavior after running my-wrapper <COMMAND> looks like this:

Don't clear the terminal on startup (as most curses programs do)
Run <COMMAND> and pass stdout and stderr through (keeping stderr stderr and stdout stdout)
after the spawned process terminated, react based on the return code being non-zero: remove the output from the terminal (as screen does it but without printing [screen is terminating]) on success, but keep it (or re-print it if necessary) otherwise


That last ("only the output of the wrapped script") requirement makes this much more complicated -- basically means you need a curses-aware library; at that point, screen or tmux becomes a very reasonable choice. Some terminals allow saving and restoring state, but it's not a feature that's standardized enough to rely on; one needs to look up its availability in the terminfo database, and realistically expect that it sometimes simply won't be available.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243237/how-to-save-restore-terminal-output on [unix.se]

Why can't you just redirect the std out and error to a file and delete that file once you are done with the process.   your-process > proc.out 2>&1

Are you looking to just clear the screen? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-the-terminal-in-python

@SteelFeather: this way I (resp. the "user") can't see what's going on in long running processes. So I'd like to show it but clean it afterwards.

@JonSG: as written in the last line, no, I don't want to kill the whole terminal history. The goal is to make it more readable by not cluttering it with useless info, while still keeping the user informed about what's going on. (imaging a compile process which I'm not interested in if everything is going well)

(btw, if you do this, and you're implementing it for more than just you, please make sure you use isatty() to disable this behavior if your program is logging to a FIFO or any other non-TTY destination; speaking as a user, applications that think they know better than I do whether and when I want to inspect log output are a peeve; applications mixing terminal control sequences into logs sent to disk, doubly so).

@frans - you can also show the output to the user by doing  program args 2>&1 | tee program.out. This will redirect the output to terminal and also to the file program.out. Also you can redirect the std err/out to different files. You can always write a wrapper where at the end you would ask user to clean up the log file and remove it based on input. e.g in case of error user might want to look at the output. and for normal runs might delete the file.

What speaks agains executing a clear after the docker command, or maybe a sleep 3; clear, so that bystanders can for 3 seconds stare with admiration to the output diasppears?

@user1934428: clear clears everything - the main reason why I don't want to keep useless stuff on the terminal is to make the rest more readable. If I didn't care about the terminal content I wouldn't have to keep it tidy in the first place or produce any output at all.

I see the point. So the, what about redirecting the output into a file? Afterwards, you can decide, whether, how and for how long you show the file. Of course you need to think of whether you really want to hide all output. What if there are error message in the output?

Depending on what terminal you are using, you could also save the screen content before your program runs, then clear everything visible afterwards, and finally restore the screen content. This approach has been discussed here.

@user1934428, ...indeed, that's a SO duplicate for what I was previously linking to [unix.se] for; good find, thank you!
