# Can I have subprocess.call write the output of the call to a string?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to do subprocess.call, and get the output of the call into a string. Can I do this directly, or do I need to pipe it to a file, and then read from it?

In other words, can I somehow redirect stdout and stderr into a string?

Comment: maybe the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/python-store-output-of-subprocess-call-in-a-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store output of subprocess.Popen call in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you can't read the output of subprocess.call() directly into a string.

In order to read the output of a command into a string, you need to use subprocess.Popen(), e.g.:

```
>>> cmd = subprocess.Popen('ls', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> cmd_out, cmd_err = cmd.communicate()
```

cmd_out will have the string with the output of the command.

Answer (score 42):

This is an extension of mantazer's answer to python3. You can still use the [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) command in python3:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "hello world"])
b'hello world\n'
```

however now it gives us a byte string. To get a real python string we need to use decode:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "hello world"]).decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
'hello world\n'
```

Using `sys.stdout.encoding` as the encoding rather than just the default `UTF-8` should make this work on any OS (at least in theory).

The trailing newline (and any other extra whitespace) can be easily removed using `.strip()`, so the final command is:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "hello world"]
                            ).decode(sys.stdout.encoding).strip()
'hello world'
```

Comment: How to write the output to a file? I tried passing the file name in command itself using redirect '>' but when next line in the python code tries to see the contents it's empty

Comment: @SanjeevkumarM Use the [stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) argument, give it a file *object* to write to (e.g. as created by [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), make sure you close it afterwards).

Comment: This was perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The `subprocess` module provides a method `check_output()` that runs the provided command with arguments (if any), and returns its output as a byte string.

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["echo", "hello world"])
print output
```

The code above will print `hello world`

See docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: How to write the output to a file? I tried passing the file name in command itself using redirect '>' but when next line in the python code tries to see the contents it's empty

Answer (score 6):

## Using `text=True` in Python 3.7+

In newer versions of Python, you can simply use `text=True` to get a string return value:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "hello"], text=True)
'hello\n'
```

Here is [what the docs say](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module):

> If `encoding` or `errors` are specified, or `text` is true, file objects for stdin, stdout and stderr are opened in text mode using the specified `encoding` and `errors` or the `io.TextIOWrapper` default. The `universal_newlines` argument is equivalent to `text` and is provided for backwards compatibility. By default, file objects are opened in binary mode.

Answer (score 2):

`subprocess.call()` takes the same arguments as `subprocess.Popen()`, which includes the `stdout` and `stderr` arguments. See the docs for details.

Comment: Looking through docs online isn't very clear to me, could you provide an example, like the other answer using Popen. Or post link with a clear example of how to get stdout value when stdout=subprocess.PIPE for example. Is the answer the same as the Popen answer?

Comment: It is in fact the same, since both functions take the same arguments.