# Getting the output of a python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to capture the output here. If, at the python prompt, I run

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["/path/to/search_by_hash.par", hash_str], 
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The return value (a list) prints to stdout, but isn't captured

```
[4460475, 4406612, 4379510]
```

I've tried following it up with

```
value = p.communicate()[0]
value
```

..but value is an empty string, not the list of ints I was expecting, and which is being printed to stdout

I experimented with the solutions from [Store output of subprocess.Popen call in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/python-store-output-of-subprocess-call-in-a-string) but haven't been able to capture the output.

UPDATE:

stderr doesn't seem to yield anything either...and the list I'm looking for *is* being printed out...just not having any luck in capturing it. See below:

```
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(["/home/jfry/tools/search_by_hash.par", hash_str], 
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> 
[4460475, 4406612, 4379510]
    value, err  = p.communicate()
>>> value
''
>>> err
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `value = p.communicate()[0]`

Comment: Are you trying to capture the data being sent to the subprocess's stdout, or are you trying to capture the subprocess's exit status?

Comment: Jakob - thanks, that was a typo in my question, but not at the prompt. I've changed the question.

Comment: Adam - I want the return *value*, in this case a list of ints, e.g. [4460475, 4406612, 4379510]

Comment: add `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`, just like you already have for stdout

Comment: The answers described here should work. What does the subprocess do? Could it be closing and reopening stdout? Can you capture its output by running it from a shell and redirecting the output, i.e. `/home/jfry/tools/search_by_hash.par hash >out 2>err`?

Comment: mita -- you added the missing piece, thanks! Now I can capture stderr, and see what's up.

Comment: the title should be fixed (`s/return value/output/`) to prevent confusion..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try checking `stderr` with `p.communicate()[1]`.

Comment: Zeekay, yes, I want the output of the command -- what's being printed to the screen after I type the command. 

Unfortunately, neither p.stdout.read() nor p.communicate()[0]
 is successfully capturing the output. Instead, both give me an empty string.

Comment: @Jeff Try checking `stderr`, `p.communicate()[1] for some clue as to what's going on.

Comment: Good suggestion, but no dice. I updated the question with the exact results from the python prompt. Thanks.

Comment: OK, with mita's suggestion above to include "stderr=subprocess.PIPE" in my Popen, I'm now able to see stderr with p.communicate()[1]. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Because the accepted answer does not solve the issue (at least for me):

To capture the `stderr`-output, the following should be done:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)        
output, err = p.communicate()
```

The crucial part is the parameter `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`, without this parameter the `stderr`-output will not be captured and `err` will be `None`.

If you are interested only in the `stderr`-output  you actually may use:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)        
err = p.communicate()[1]
```

In this case `p.communicate()[0]` is `None`.

Answer (score 1):

communicate is a method. So you should call it!

```
out = p.communicate()
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo in my question, but not at the prompt. I've changed the question.