# Redirect subprocess to a variable as a string

Tags: python

With the following command, it prints '640x360'

```
>>> command = subprocess.call(['mediainfo', '--Inform=Video;%Width%x%Height%', 
'/Users/Desktop/1video.mp4'])

640x360
```

How would I set a variable equal to the string of the output, so I can get `x='640x360'`? Thank you.

Comment: Answers should not be edited into the question. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) on [meta].

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using 2.7, you can use subprocess.check_output():

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> output = subprocess.check_output(['echo', '640x360'])
>>> print output
640x360
```

If not:

```
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['echo', '640x360'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p.communicate()
('640x360\n', None)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "-al"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
```

Comment: I was just typing out the same answer, but just wanted to say that I'd suggest using Popen rather than call because it's slightly more explicit and does the same thing.  subprocess.call is just a convenience function for Popen.

Comment: but call() prints the output and returns the exit code of your process, that is 0 if you process suceeded.

Comment: That's a good point that I had forgotten about.  Given that, call() may be the better way to go in pre 2.7, but Scott Anderson's answer likely is better in 2.7 since it automatically checks for nominal exit status.