# Cannot parse xml from subprocess.Popen output in Python

Tags: python, xml-parsing, subprocess, xml.etree, celementtree

I'm using this library to parse my xml:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as xml
```

The xml input to the parser is an output of `subprocess.Popen`:

```
XMLFile = subprocess.Popen(xml_command,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, executable="/bin/ksh").communicate()[0]
root = xml.XML(XMLFile)
```

I get this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 36] File name too long: ' <?xml version=\...'
```

However, when I pass the xml generated from the same command `xml_command` as file, it works perfectly fine:

```
root = xml.parse("/home/test.xml")
```

Comment: You are passing the entire xml file as filename , so you are getting that error.Figure out how to get the filename and pass it to `xml.XML`....

Comment: `XMLFile` is xmldata not xmlfile

Comment: That's why I'm using xml.XML with XMLFile and xml.parse with the file path.

Comment: Is it possible that somehow `xml_command` ends up holding the XML data and the error comes from the `subprocess.Popen()` invocation? I would recommend putting a debug statement between the two lines just to double-check you know where the exception is coming from - `IOError` is the sort of generic exception which can come from almost anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as xml
p = subprocess.Popen(xml_command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, executable="/bin/ksh")
text, err = p.communicate()
root = xml.fromstring(text)
```

with python 2.6.6

> [Store output of subprocess.Popen call in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring
root = fromstring(subprocess.check_output(['/bin/ksh']))
```