# Assign output to a variable instead to a Output file

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

Here is the Python code:

```
import subprocess 

cmnd = ["ffmpeg", "-i", "/home/xincoz/test/connect.flv", "-acodec", "copy", "-ss", "00:00:00", "-t", "00:00:30", "/home/xincoz/test/output.flv"]

subprocess.call(cmnd)
```

Here I get the 30sec long video output file output.flv from connect.flv video. But i want to store that 30sec long binary data in a variable instead of copying that into an output file.
How can I able to do that?

Please help me. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/python-store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to tell to ffmpeg to output to stdout and also tell if the output format. Then from python, as @matino said, use Popen to read what was written to stdout:

```
cmnd = ["ffmpeg", "-i", "/your/file.avi", "-acodec", "copy", "-ss", "00:00:00", "-t", "00:00:30", "-f", "avi", "pipe:1"]

p = subprocess.Popen(cmnd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = p.communicate()

print len(out) # print the length of the data received
```