# check if host key is changed in python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, ssh-keys

I want to check if server signature is changed in my python code, in bash that is comparing

```
ssh-keyscan IP
```

with

```
ssh-keygen -F IP
```

(ofcourse not exactly comparing but some process needed)

How can I do that in python? For example in paramiko or without using it (preferred).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the subprocess popen in combination with communicate for that purpose.

See [2502833/python-store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/python-store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string)

Comment: I want pythonic way to do it