# Error in Popen when using subprocess.py in windows

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "script/oic_flow_tests.py", line 232, in <module>
   p1 =Popen(["./%s.py" % args.server], stdout=PIPE)
 File "C:\python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
   errread, errwrite)
 File "C:\python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
   startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] Le fichier spÚcifiÚ est introuvable
```

(The French error means "file not found")

I've tried to fix it by adding `shell=True` in `Popen`, but then another error appears:

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"
```

Comment: Hi there. You should post the relevant code, but it appears that the file you're trying to open doesn't exist... Perhaps you got a path name wrong? You should also try to make your posts in English. I translated the Python error for you now, since most people here don't do French :-)

Comment: Don't use `shell=True` -- instead, understand what was wrong with your Popen call in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

`"./%s.py" % args.server` isn't a file.

1. What is `args.server`? Why do you think the file is in your current directory?
2. You can omit the `./` -- it doesn't do anything here.

Comment: thank u for the response , i've fixed it but a new error appears Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "oic_flow_tests.py", line 236, in <module>
    _cnf = json.loads(p1.stdout.read())
  File "C:\python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: @user3301734, It sounds like `p1.stdout.read()` isn't a JSON string.  You need to look at it to see what it *actually* is.

Comment: (As an aside, the normal way to get the full stdout is the communicate method.) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/python-store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string/2502883#2502883