# Getting output from a Python script subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, return-value

This may be a stupid question but I have a Python script that starts a subprocess (also a Python script) and I need that subprocess to return three integers. How do I get those return values from the Python script that starts the subprocess? Do I have to output the integers to stdout and then use the check_output() function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store output of subprocess.Popen call in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string)

Comment: Cheers, I know how to get output back from a subprocess - that answer you linked to is good or I could use subprocess.check_output(). In terms of passing back output from a python script running as a subprocess, is it common practice just to write the return values to stdout() and get them back in that manner?

Comment: If you're forking out python jobs, then perhaps the multiprocesssing module is a better fit?  (especially the Pool functions like multiprocessing.Pool.map)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is *Yes*... I want my +15 reputation!! **:-D**

No, seriously... Once you start dealing with subprocesses, the only way you really have to communicate with them is through files (which is what `stdout`, `stderr` and such are, in the end)

So what you're gonna have to do is grab the output and check what happened (and maybe the spawned process' `exit_code`, which will be zero if everything goes well) Bear in mind that the contents of `stdout` (which is what you'll get with the `check_output` function) is an string. So in order to get the three items, you'll have to split that string somehow...

For instance:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(["echo", "1", "2", "3"])
print "Output: %s" % output
int1, int2, int3 = output.split(' ')
print "%s, %s, %s" % (int1, int2, int3)
```

Comment: Thank you! Wow I assumed there might be a less straight forward, more 'correct' way to do it but at least this is simple! (I'll accept this answer when it lets me)

Comment: So do I just have my subprocess print() / sys.stdout.write() its 3 return values?

Comment: Yeah, either way (`print` will output a newline at the end... `stdout.write` won't)