# How can I capture the result of a python script in calling python script?

Tags: python, return, subprocess

Newbie in python.

I'm trying to call a python script from a python script, for most of which I'm successful except capturing the result.

a.py

```
status = subprocess.call("python /hosting/apps/b.py"+" "+server+" "+port+" "+sid, shell=True)
```

b.py 

Here in second script,I'm doing some computation and trying to pass back a variable named status using print and return

```
print status;
return status;
```

This doesn't seems to work. Is this the correct way of doing this?

Comment: do you need to use subprocess? why not do `import b` from a.py? (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: Use Popen and read the stdout of the process. Instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string

Comment: you should *import* the `b` module and call appropriate functions to get the result directly (perhaps using `threading`, `multiprocessing`, etc modules if you need multiple threads, processes) instead of running the `b.py` as an external process and capturing its output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two options suggested in comments are probably your best bets.  Here are small working examples:

Here, `b.py` sets `status` with the current time, and prints it.

**b.py**

```
import time

status = time.time()

print status
```

**a.py (subprocess)**

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('python -u b.py', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

(out,_) = p.communicate()

b_status = out

print b_status
```

Output:

```
1427685638.46
```

(Note, this extra space here is intended, `b_status` will have a trailing newline.  This is something to keep in mind.)

**a.py (import)**

```
import b

b_status = b.status   # Directly access b.py's status variable

print b_status
```

Output:

```
1427685801.45
1427685801.45
```

Note that `status` is displayed twice using the second method.  Once in b.py's `print status` and once in a.py's `print b_status`.  Don't let it confuse you, `b_status` contains only the timestamp, and no trailing newline like the first approach.

(In fact, it's "displayed" twice in the first method as well, but the output from b.py is captured by a.py, which is how `b_status` is set when using that approach.)

In general, I think importing is a better alternative, since printing and parsing it is much more error prone.

Comment: Thanks jedwards, I tried below with no luck

`p = subprocess.Popen('python -u b.py'+' '+server+' '+port+' '+sid, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(out,_) = p.communicate()
b_status = out
print b_status
f = open('/tmp/test_log.log','a')
f.write('\n')
f.write(b_status)
f.close()
`
Not sure whats wrong here. But couldn't get it to work

Comment: Could you give us the exact error message ?

Comment: If I try the exact popen code mentioned above in your answer, I get the below error

`$ python a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 3, in ?
    p = subprocess.Popen('python -u b.py', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 550, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 996, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: Okie, os.popen worked for me. But I encountered a new problem. When I run a.py manually everything works.. but a.py is being triggered from an application in my case. And this os.popen isn't working during this process.

Comment: @pradeep You may need to specify the full path to pyrthon then -- so instead of `python -u` you'd want something like `/usr/local/bin/python -u` or whatever `which python` says.

Comment: Actually, it required full path on the child script. instead of a.py it required /hosting/apps..../a.py

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=check%20output#subprocess.check_output) rather than `subprocess.call()` to retrieve the content of the standard output (in which you have written with `print` and not `return` as [BBrown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29337544/1219073) noted) in a variable. This method is pretty general and is not limited to python scripts (you could call any accessible executable).

```
status = subprocess.check_output("python /hosting/apps/b.py"+" "+server+" "+port+" "+sid, shell=True)
```

However, you will retrieve the output as a string (everything that you printed during the execution of `b.py`) that you will need to parse. What you probably want to do is to define a function in the `b.py` module:

```
## b.py
def main(server, port, sid):
  # Do things
  return status
```

and call it from `a.py` (provided that b is in your [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path)):

```
## a.py
import b
status = b.main(server, port, sid)
```

Comment: subprocess.check_output didnt work for me. My second script doesnt get executed. Any suggesstions?

Comment: I'm running python 2.4.3. Is check_output available only in later versions?

Comment: Indeed, `check_output` is _New in version 2.7_ according to the documentation. In this case you will need to use [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/node235.html) as @jedwards mentioned. You should upgrade if possible, this python version is almost ten years old.

Answer (score 0):

return won't return a value from a module (i.e. file); that's only for a function created with the `def` keyword. You could set the `sys.stdout`. See [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python) .