# how to split output of system call in python into list of words?

Tags: python

I run the following:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["uptime"])
```

I get:

> 19:36:49 up 4 days,  5:58, 14 users,  load average: 0.46, 0.32, 0.40

Question: I want to split this string into words (each separated by blankspace) so that I can check for a certain amount of load. How do I do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store output of subprocess.Popen call in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `subprocess.check_output`.

Like so (in the interpreter):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> output = subprocess.check_output("uptime", shell=False)
>>> print output.split()
['18:06:24', 'up', '16', 'days,', '22:40,', '8', 'users,', 'load', 'average:', '0.30,', '0.45,', '0.59']
```

For more, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import timedelta

with open('/proc/uptime', 'r') as f:
    uptime_seconds = float(f.readline().split()[0])
    uptime_string = str(timedelta(seconds = uptime_seconds))

print(uptime_string)
```

Comment: I get the following: words = string.split() 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Works, but I am interested in the three load averages from the uptime command, not in the uptime.