# Is it possible in python to bind event handler on stdout of subprocess

Tags: python, asynchronous

I have the following external asynchronous code, that I need to run from my python script (external.js):

```
var i = o
setInterval(function(){
    i++;
    console.log('item ' + i);//I need to evoke processOutput function on every console.log
}, 1000)
```

What I need to do in my python script is to catch every output portion(console.log) from external script and handle it:

```
import subprocess  

def processOutput( consoleLogFromExternal )
    #do stuff

proc = subprocess.Popen(['phantomjs', 'external.js'], 
                        stdout=processOutput)         #doesn't work, of course
```

Are there any ways to do this? Solution on Python 2.7 would be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string

Comment: @sobolevn I need some sort of event firing on output change, because external.js is meant to loop forever. In your example they only store output in variable, which is not the same task I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You can extend the variable class and check the input on `write`.