# My python subprocess call did not work in crontab why?

Tags: python, hadoop, cron, datastax-enterprise

My current approach is to first remove the old model, save the new model , using the shell  is no problem , but it just doesn't work automatically using crontab. Any idea why or how to solve this? Thanks for the help.

The error is that main programm does not wait for the subprocess.call to return. I think that this is the problem but not sure.

This is my current command:

```
subprocess.call('dse hadoop fs -rmr /root/recommend_model', shell=True)
```

Comment: How is the path set up in crontab? In particular, is the `dse` executable in that path? Check your logs!

Comment: When running a cron job redirect stdout and stderr to a file you can read using `command > cron.out 2>&1`. You can then read cron.out to find what the actual error is

Comment: @dhke and spade  The error is that main programm does not wait for the subprocess.call to return. I think that this is the problem but not sure. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution just to check that it was correctly executed is to wait a returncode.

Here the link to subprocess module:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

You can wait the return code in you script:

```
if (subprocess.call(command, args) == 0):
    print("We are proceeding)
else:
    print("Something went wrong executing %s" % command)
```

Additionally try as suggested to redirect to a log file your script execution with 2>&1 > mickey.log

Last but not least some subprocess/os.system suggestions available here:
 [Controlling a python script from another script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620656/controlling-a-python-script-from-another-script/36621078#36621078)

[python: run external program and direct output to file and wait for finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717846/python-run-external-program-and-direct-output-to-file-and-wait-for-finish/36718106#36718106)

Please let me know if this solve your issue.

Comment: In addition with  subprocess.call(['python.exe', command,args]) under WIN os, it is possible that you will have to specify the python to execute the call, but this is not your case as I can see from command :-)   Have a nice day.