# How to stop PiCamera preview on keystroke?

Tags: camera, keystroke

I made a code through python to operate a preview of my PiCamera, I have set the time to 10 seconds, then automatically turns off. However I am unsure how I would be able to have a keystroke to stop the camera and return to the previous screen?
At the moment I am able to view for 10 seconds, and nothing else, the usual ctrl-c and various other keys does not work.

How would I be able to integrate a keystroke into the code following to stop the script and return to normal screen?

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep

camera = PiCamera()

camera.start_preview()
sleep(10)
camera.stop_preview()
```

Comment: Maybe you can use something like while loop or if you can get an input then choose a special character.  Anyway welcome with your first question ;)

Comment: If you just want to run endless your camera and continue with something else, then you can use subprocess module and open (Popen) a new process for the camera.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, do you have any idea how that would be placed onto my code? I am unsure of the wording required, I have not done a keystroke before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subprocess module you can check on the official page:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

A possible way to implement with subprocess.Popen is here on SO:

[Controlling a python script from another script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620656/controlling-a-python-script-from-another-script/36621078#36621078)

Another possibility is to use multiprocesses or multithreading module. For instance creation of a thread can be done and you can take care of an ID :-)

All the possibility will lead you to learn a bit more of python!

My better suggestion will be to create easily a thread (https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html --> here for python 3), get the ID and leave it run.

If you want to terminate the camera running, then terminate the thread :-)