# How execute powershell or command-prompt script and print output in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, command-prompt

I'm trying to run and print mypowershell script from python
Or run cmd command and print result in python
2 file is in directory "C:\workspace\test" --> program.ps1 And program.py

powershell script --> program.ps1 :

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize
```

cmd command:

```
powershell -noexit "& ""C:\workspace\test\program.ps1"""
```

both commands print installed programs in windows
how i can run one of the two command in python?
ه'm grateful you give an example

Comment: Did you look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: Yes, I read this but did not notice

Comment: Please explain this to me for this question

Comment: Using the `call` function will, by default, execute the command that you give and print the output to stdout.  So, to execute the cmd command you have there, you would pass `['powershell', '-noexit', '&', 'C:\\workspace\\test\\program.ps1']` to `call`

Comment: Tanxs user2791611
This code print result in command line , but i want print output to variable for use.

Comment: how can transfer output to variable

Comment: In that case, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string

Comment: Thank you for your help
Done