# subprocess.Popen process stdout returning empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have this python code

```
input()
print('spam')
```

saved as `ex1.py`

in interactive shell

```
>>>from subprocess import Popen ,PIPE
>>>a=Popen(['python.exe','ex1.py'],stdout=PIPE,stdin=PIPE)

>>> a.communicate()

(b'', None)

>>>
```

why it is not printing the `spam`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store output of subprocess.Popen call in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string)

Comment: @Gator_Python nope, those examples do not have any input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input expects a whole line, but your input is empty. So there is only an exception written to `stderr` and nothing to `stdout`. At least provide a newline as input:

```
>>> a = Popen(['python3', 'ex1.py'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
>>> a.communicate(b'\n')
(b'spam\n', None)
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just added `stderr=PIPE` and then ran the program, and it caught the error as  `(b'', b'Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File "receive_from_sub.py", line 5, in <module>\r\n    input()\r\nEOFError: EOF when reading a line\r\n')`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `stderr` piping:

```
from subprocess import Popen ,PIPE

proc = Popen(['python.exe','ex1.py'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
print(out, err)
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is `subprocess.check_output`

Comment: Can you explain bit more that how your answer solves above question ?

Comment: Hi Rakesh, did you see the question I linked to in the comments? [store the output of subprocess.popen call in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string)

This function is specifically for getting the output of another process.

Comment: While your answer might be correct, it's much better to explain why it's correct. That educates the OP helping them understand how to avoid the problem in the future.