# returning several outputs from c++ application

Tags: python, c++

I'm writing a c++ program which evaluates the result of 3 values.

I would like call this application by a python script, which should receive these values.

The problem is that c++ main function, returns one integer value only.

What's the best approach to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: One method is described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string by using stdout or stderr.

Comment: Returning a result from main, that *isn't* a program termination status, is kind-of a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You could save the intermediate values in a file or you could write to `stdout` in the c++ code e.g.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "param1,param2,param3\n";
}
```

Now in python use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) to execute the c++ code and capture `stdout` using a `PIPE`.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen('./nameofyourexe', stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

output, err = process.communicate()

if process.returncode == 0:
    print(output.decode().strip().split(','))
else:
    print('error: %s' % err.decode())
```

It's up to you in which format you output the three parameters. I put them all on the same line, separated by commas and simply `split` in the python code. You may choose to do it differently, depending upon your needs.

After compiling the c++ and running the python from the same directory. The output is

```
['param1', 'param2', 'param3']
```

**Note:**

I used `'./nameofyourexe'` (prefix with `./`) to execute the program from the current directory. This may not work on windows (I'm on linux) or if you execute it from a different directory than the current one. To get around this you could pass the `cwd` parameter to `Popen` specifying the directory containing the exe.