# python execute command with multiple arguments

Tags: python

I want to run the following command using Python on a Mac OS X computer:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -K $(echo -n 'blabla1' | xxd -p) -iv blabla2 -in /tmp/clair -nopad -out /tmp/crypte1 -d
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
clef = 'blabla1'
iv = 'blabla2'
arguments = ['openssl','enc', '-aes-128-cbc', '-K $(echo -n \'%s\' | xxd -p)' % clef ,'-iv' ,'%s' % iv,'-in', '/tmp/clair','-nopad','-out','/tmp/crypte1','-d']
execute = Popen(arguments, stdout=PIPE)
out, err = execute.communicate()
```

The command works fine from a terminal but I get an error from the Python script:

```
unknown option '-K $(echo -n 'blabla1' | xxd -p)'
```

I have tried several variants of python shell functions (`os.system` for example), but I have a problem in each case.

Comment: Mightn't that be a shell error message?

Comment: No because the command works fine in the terminal. I think python is changing something...

Comment: @Bob5421. Nope. Will explain momentarily.

Comment: `Popen` does not run a bash that could expand `-K $(...)`.

Comment: You neglect to mention the fact that you got *other* error messages from `os.system`, and to show those messages.

Comment: Also, `'%s' % iv` is just `iv`, or `str(iv)` if you're paranoid.

Comment: Might be a good time to select an answer?

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of things that users often take for granted when using a shell. Some examples are:

- Variable expansion (`${var}`)
- Input/output redirection (`cmd > out < in`)
- Pipes (`cmd1 | cmd2`)
- Subshell creation (`$(cmd)`)

All of these are features that the shell sets up *before* passing the actual command to the system. Python's [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module does not do any of these things for you automatically, but it does give you the tools to emulate them.

You have correctly redirected your output to a pipe for your Python process to pick up. However, the subshell created by `$(echo -n 'blabla1' | xxd -p)` is not something that will get processed the way you want without a shell. There are two simple workarounds.

1. The quick and dirty solution is to pass the entire command line in as a string to [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) and set [`shell=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

   ```
   execute = Popen("openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -K $(echo -n 'blabla1' | xxd -p) "
                   "-iv blabla2 -in /tmp/clair -nopad -out /tmp/crypte1 -d",
                   shell=True)
   ```

   This will pass the string to a shell instead of directly to the system, thereby giving you access all the behaviors that you expect from a shell. This approach has major security problems, and is not generally recommended. However, it is very easy, and it will get you started.
2. Implement the convenience of `$(... | ...)` in your code directly by [capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2502833/2988730) the output of `xxd` to a string using [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run). This is lengthier, but probably more robust and portable in the long run. It is certainly the option I would chose in a production environment:

   ```
   from subprocess import Popen, run

   value = run(['xxd', '-p'], input='blabla1', universal_newlines=True).stdout
   execute = Popen(['openssl', 'enc', '-aes-128-cbc', '-K', value,
                    '-iv', 'blabla2', '-in', '/tmp/clair', '-nopad',
                    '-out', '/tmp/crypte1', '-d'])
   ```

Since you are setting up your own pipes, you don't need to call `echo` any more (you never did really, `xxd -p <<< 'blabla1'` would have worked fine), and `-K` needs to be a separate argument.

Comment: I have tried your solution 1. I get this error: "hex string is too long
invalid hex key value". And i have no error if i launch directly from my terminal

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between running `echo ... | xxd -p` from the command line and running `run(['xxd', '-p'], input='blabla1', universal_newlines=True).stdout` in the Python shell?

Comment: @Bob5421. I'm assuming you were referring to the second option by the way.

Comment: @Bob5421. Could you also please edit a list of the alternatives you've tried and the errors they gave you into your question?

Comment: In fact i am wondering if the problem is not that some chars are not encoded on 1 byte

Comment: @Bob5421. I'd love to help you figure it out, but I kinda need the information I requested to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess` adds quotes `"` to the argument `"-K $(echo -n 'blabla1' | xxd -p)"`. You can check by

```
print(subprocess.list2cmdline(execute.args))
```

**Output:**

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc "-K $(echo -n 'blabla1' | xxd -p)" -iv blabla2 -in /tmp/clair -nopad -out /tmp/crypte1 -d
```

Comment: That is a very minor issue and does not address the actual problem with the subshell OP is trying to create.

Comment: Well, of course its not full solution but it addresses the problem of `Popen(arguments, stdout=PIPE)` with subsell. Thank you for your comprehensive answser.

Comment: I've removed my downvote. You are right that this is not really a minor issue, and you did address the immediate question, even if the question is incomplete.