# How to write output of terminal to file with format?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to save result of script to file. Example of script:

```
import os

def scan_ip():
    ip2 = raw_input('Enter ip of target: ')
    target = 'nmap -sP {}'.format(ip2)
    os.system(target + > '123.txt')
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please review the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour as well as how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you trying to save the target to the txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do in this way. First you need to call the external command with [output captured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string), and then write the output you captured to a file:

```
import subprocess

ip2 = raw_input('Enter ip of target: ')
p = subprocess.Popen(["nmap", "-sP", ip2], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
with open('123.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(out)
```

Comment: Basic idea is right, but I think you want to use user input to execute a command consisting of `['nmap`,  `'-sP'`,  `'<user input>']`.

Comment: @martineau yes, I copied wrong code. fixed. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('123.txt', 'w') as my_file:
    my_file.write(target)
```

Comment: nmap -sP 192.168.1.104

Comment: i want output of this os.system into file not command pliiiz help