# capturing output in a variable in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variables, output

This is a silly question, but it's giving me a lot of trouble.
I'm trying to capture an output into a variable

```
a='jobid'
p=exec(a)
print(p)
output:None
```

You guys might say why not just use the variable 'a' rather than executing it, but I have a cascading function next to it. And I can't use the variable 'a'.And the value 'job ID' in the variable 
'a' comes from a data frame and needs to catch value, as 'job ID' is a parameter in my code. Can anyone please help me out?

I also tried the below code:

```
a='jobid'
p=exec('print(jobid)')
print(p)
```

But it didn't worked out.

Comment: `exec()` doesn't return anything. Hence `p=exec(a) ;print(p)` will print `None`.

Comment: Not only `exec` does not return anything, `print` does not return anything as well, so I'm very confused as to what you expect `p` to be

Comment: Yuo probably want to [use subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect `sys.stdout` and use a [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o) object to catch the value:

```
import sys
from io import StringIO

something = lambda:print('I have been run')
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = catcher = StringIO()
exec('something()')
sys.stdout = old_stdout
print(catcher.get_value())
```

Or, for safety, you can use [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) to do the same thing:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
catcher = StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(catcher):
     exec('something()')
print(catcher.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Try the following:

```
b='a="jobid"\nprint(a)'
exec(b)
```