# Calling a Python script within a batch script and handling output stream

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, vlc

Previously I had a `.bat` script that triggers an STB blaster script, kills any open sessions of `VLC`, then starts a new one to encode capture card raw video output into a transport stream. This stream is the used as the input to a PVR program I am using.

The batch script looked like this:

```
"G:\Visual Studio 2017\C++ Projects\SkyQChannelChanger\Release\SkyQChannelChanger.exe" %1

taskkill /f /im vlc.exe /t

"G:\VLC\vlc" --ffmpeg-hw --avcodec-hw=any dshow:// :dshow-vdev="Video (00 Pro Capture HDMI 4K+)" :dshow-adev="Audio (2- 00 Pro Capture HDMI 4K+)" :dshow-threads=8 :dshow-aspect-ratio=16\:9 :dshow-size="3840x2160" :dshow-pixel_format=yuv444p16le :dshow-tune=film :dshow-preset=lossless :dshow-profile=main10 show-vcodec=x265 :dshow-fps=50 :dshow-crf=0 :dshow-acodec=mp4a :dshow-stereo-mode=5 :dshow-force-surround-sound=0 :dshow-ab=128 :dshow-samplerate=44100 :no-dshow-config :live-caching=300 --sout "#transcode{venc=ffmpeg,vcodec=mp2v,threads=8,aspect=16:9,width=3840,height=2160,fps=50,acodec=a52,ab=1500,channels=2,samplerate=48000,soverlay}:standard{access=file,dst=-,mux=ts}"
```

However, I want to move the `VLC` call to a `Python` file that the `.bat` script calls. This means the new batch script looks like this:

```
@echo off

"G:\Visual Studio 2017\C++ Projects\SkyQChannelChanger\Release\SkyQChannelChanger.exe" %1

taskkill /f /im vlc.exe /t

"G:\HTPC Scripts\NPVR Command Line\Command Line.py"
```

And the Python script being called looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

os.chdir('G:\\VLC\\')

startupinfo = None
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW

process = subprocess.Popen([
'vlc',
'--ffmpeg-hw',
'--avcodec-hw=any',
'dshow:// :dshow-vdev="Video (00 Pro Capture HDMI 4K+)" :dshow-adev="Audio (2- 00 Pro Capture HDMI 4K+)"',
':dshow-threads=8',
':dshow-aspect-ratio=16\:9',
':dshow-size="3840x2160"',
':dshow-pixel_format=yuv444p16le',
':dshow-tune=film',
':dshow-preset=lossless',
':dshow-profile=main10',
'show-vcodec=x265',
':dshow-fps=50',
':dshow-crf=0',
':dshow-acodec=mp4a',
':dshow-stereo-mode=5',
':dshow-force-surround-sound=0',
':dshow-ab=128',
':dshow-samplerate=44100',
':no-dshow-config',
':live-caching=300',
'--sout',
'"#transcode{venc=ffmpeg,vcodec=mp2v,threads=8,aspect=16:9,width=3840,height=2160,fps=50,acodec=a52,ab=1500,channels=2,samplerate=48000,soverlay}:standard{access=file,dst=-,mux=ts}"',
], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

Both the batch script and the `Python` script appear to work so far as the batch script calls the `Python` script successfully and the `Python` script in turn opens `VLC` successfully.

However, the issue, which I really don't understand is that `Python` doesn't appear to be passing the encoded video ***to the shell*** if that makes sense?

My PVR software now cannot detect the stream. So my question is, how can I amend the `subprocess` part of my code so that it fully replicates calling the `VLC` commands ***directly from the command line?*** I have tried using `shell=True`, but this has no effect...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I think `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` only causes the output to be piped to a file object, not your python script's stdout. You still need to write code to actually get the content from `p.stdout` and print it. See [Popen.stdout](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects)

Comment: hi - i am a bit confused about what i am supposed to be amending looking at the subprocess documentation...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string

Comment: im afraid that made no difference at all...