# subprocess.run output is empty (python 3.8)

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm trying to capture the output of a command with the following code:

```
lines = subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-hide_banner', '-nostats', '-i', in_filename, '-vn', '-af', 'silencedetect=n={}:d={}'.format(silence_threshold, silence_duration), '-f', 'null', '-'], capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True, check=True, encoding='utf-8').stdout 
print (lines)
```

But lines is an empty string and nothing is printed.
When `capture_output=True` is removed, the correct output is showed (without printing it).

I tested many combinations, including removing all the `subprocess.run` parameters and only include `capture_output=True` with the same result.

I also tested with few argument for a minimal example: `subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-version'], capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True, check=True, encoding='utf-8').stdout`

Also tested `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` as `subprocess.run` arguments instead of `capture_output=True`

I can't figure out what is happening. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `check_output()` from `subprocess` and `subprocess.Popen().communicate()`? Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2502883/1509809)

Comment: According to the Python documentation I guess subprocess.run should be the prefered method. Anyway, I had always problems when using check_output() from subprocess

Answer (score 3):

By default `ffmpeg` [logs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Generic-options) to `stderr`. You use `capture_output=True`, so `run()` func will capture `stdout` and `stderr` values

Q-1) Lines is an empty string and nothing is printed.

A-1) This is normal because ffmpeg not log to stdout by default.

Q-2) When `capture_output=True` is removed, the correct output is showed (without printing it).

A-2) This is what we expected, when you remove `capture_output=True` then `ffmpeg` logs to `stderr` (to your terminal/console by default) and you will see ffmpeg output on the screen(`stdin,stdout,and stderr` [these](https://linux.die.net/man/3/stdout) are typically attached to the user's terminal). When you use `capture_output=True`, ffmpeg's logs go to the kernel `pipe` file-like object in the RAM (In Unix and Linux, no knowledge about windows). That's why you don't see any output in the terminal/console without `print()`'ing the captured stdout

`subprocess.run()` func will return `CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)` instance and you can get `stdout` attribute's value but we don't need this, we need `stderr` attribute's value because `ffmpeg` logs to `stderr` by default as i said above.

You need to modify it like ;

```
lines = subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-hide_banner', '-nostats', '-i', in_filename, '-vn', '-af', 'silencedetect=n={}:d={}'.format(silence_threshold, silence_duration), '-f', 'null', '-'], capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True, check=True, encoding='utf-8').stderr
print (lines)
```