# Python os.system output value '0' in ListBox

Tags: python, windows

I'm new to Python programming (Windows) and now I have a problem.

I'm trying to print the following:

```py
def volc():
        os.system(r'Vol C:')
print(volc)
```

So, that works as it should: it prints C: drives serial number in console.

But the problem is that I want it to be seen in ListBox.
If i try:

```py
def volc():
        os.system(r'Vol C:')
Lb1.insert(1, volc)
```

I get value as "0" in listbox.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

---

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import subprocess
from subprocess import check_output
import os

root = tk.Tk()
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

def volc():
        command = "Vol C:"
        output = check_output(command.split())        
def get_info():
        response = messagebox.askokcancel('Please wait... ', 'Accessing current Hard Drive IDs... Please click "OK". ')
        if response == True:       
            Lb1.insert(6, volc)

button1 = tk.Button (root, text='Get all the Hard Drive IDs ',command=get_info,bg='green',fg='white')
canvas1.create_window(150, 200, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

There is a part of it. The rest is not important.

Comment: your volc() is a function, you're inserting a function into the Lb1. Your function volc is supposed to return the value output, then your get_info is supposed to call the function, get output and insert to Lb1. See my modified answer.

Answer (score 1):

In python, `os.system()` will execute the command and return you the return code of the command, not the output of the command. [os.system python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system)

You need to use something like subprocess to get the output of your command. For example

```py
from subprocess import check_output

def volc():
    command = "Vol C:"
    return check_output(command.split())

def get_info():
    ...
    cmd_output = volc()
    Lb1.insert(6, cmd_output)
```

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2502883/1509809) for other python versions

*Modified answer based on the new info provided by OP*

Comment: That gives me:<function output at 0x000001E61F03FCA0>

Comment: Can you show me your code? output is not a function, it's the actual output of the command. You can try printing the output before calling the last line `Lb1.insert(...)`